# Directory-tree listing in Python

Tags: python, file, directory, subdirectory, directory-tree

How do I get a list of all files (and directories) in a given directory in Python?

Comment: recursively or not? Clarify please. For non recursive solution see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973473/getting-a-list-of-all-subdirectories-in-the-current-directory

Answer (score 637, accepted):

This is a way to traverse every file and directory in a directory tree:

```
import os

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    # print path to all subdirectories first.
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, subdirname))

    # print path to all filenames.
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

    # Advanced usage:
    # editing the 'dirnames' list will stop os.walk() from recursing into there.
    if '.git' in dirnames:
        # don't go into any .git directories.
        dirnames.remove('.git')
```

Comment: And if you run this code (as is) from the Python Shell, recall that Ctrl+C will halt output to said shell. ;)

Comment: This will *recursively* list files and directories

Comment: You can even edit the dirnames list to prevent it from recursing down some paths.

Comment: @Clément "When topdown is True, the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames before it resumes walk() again." from http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: The simpler way to ignore some directories is to not add them to dirnames in the first place `for subdirname in dirnames: if subdirname != '.git'`

Comment: @smci You've misunderstood. You've given a code snippet for not printing out the name of the .git directory. Removing it from dirnames causes the code to not recurse into the .git subdirectory.

Comment: Oh I see, you intended to print every dirname, then recurse into every dirname except .git

Answer (score 544):

You can use

```
os.listdir(path)
```

For reference and more os functions look here:

- Python 2 docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir
- Python 3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

Comment: well the original question is just vague enough to not know whether they wanted a recursive solution. "all files in a directory" could be interpreted as  recursive.

Comment: @Tommy, a “directory” is a clearly defined data structure, and it refers to "ls" rather than "ls -R".  Besides, almost all UNIX tools don't work recursively by default.  I don't know what the questioner *meant* but what he *wrote* was clear.

Comment: The python 3 docs tell you to use `os.scandir` instead however, since in many cases it allows you to prevent system calls, giving a free speedup (both IPC and IO are slow).

Comment: listdir gives you the only the filename in the directory, is there a method available to get full path?

Comment: @greperror You can use [*os.path.abspath*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) for getting the full path. Also, to check if a given path is a file, use the [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) or `os.path.isdir`.

Answer (score 135):

Here's a helper function I use quite often:

```
import os

def listdir_fullpath(d):
    return [os.path.join(d, f) for f in os.listdir(d)]
```

Comment: A generator would be better.

Comment: @RobertSiemer that depends on the usage. In many cases, a list would be better, but I guess a generator is more versatile since it can be converted to a list. It depends on whether you're looking for, versatility or something a little bit more streamlined.

Comment: It's been ten years, but I think I did it this way because os.listdir() returns a list and I was imitating that.

Answer (score 83):

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("C:\\temp"):
    print  filename
```

Comment: `r'C:\temp'` is clearer and preferred to `"C:\\temp"` Rawstrings are preferable to escpaing backslashes.

Comment: @smci: Actually `"C:/temp"` is what would be preferred.

Comment: @martineau: there is no consensus; this is like emacs-vs-vi. Forward-slash is preferable because it can't be misinterpreted as escaping chars, but backward-slash is still more popular...

Comment: @smci: Forward slash is also portable and doesn't require a special prefix. I wouldn't criticize anyone for doing it the way the OP did. Anyhow, as far as popularity goes, we must move in different circles.  `;¬)`

Answer (score 15):

If you need globbing abilities, there's a module for that as well. For example:

```
import glob
glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
```

will return something like:

```
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html).

Comment: that's really awesome! can you have negation in those matching expression? like everything except files matching `THIS` pattern?

Comment: @CharlieParker: You can't do it directly with `glob`, but you can fairly easily with it or `os.listdir()` in conjunction with the `re` regular expression module — see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13032338/355230) to another question.

Answer (score 11):

For files in current working directory without specifying a path

**Python 2.7:**

```
import os
os.listdir('.')
```

**Python 3.x:**

```
import os
os.listdir()
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
import os
for top, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for nm in files:       
        print os.path.join(top, nm)
```

Comment: In one line: [top + os.sep + f for top, dirs, files in os.walk('./') for f in files]

Answer (score 7):

While `os.listdir()` is fine for generating a list of file and dir names, frequently you want to do more once you have those names - and in Python3, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) makes those other chores simple. Let's take a look and see if you like it as much as I do.

To list dir contents, construct a Path object and grab the iterator:

```
In [16]: Path('/etc').iterdir()
Out[16]: <generator object Path.iterdir at 0x110853fc0>
```

If we want just a list of names of things:

```
In [17]: [x.name for x in Path('/etc').iterdir()]
Out[17]:
['emond.d',
 'ntp-restrict.conf',
 'periodic',
```

If you want just the dirs:

```
In [18]: [x.name for x in Path('/etc').iterdir() if x.is_dir()]
Out[18]:
['emond.d',
 'periodic',
 'mach_init.d',
```

If you want the names of all conf files in that tree:

```
In [20]: [x.name for x in Path('/etc').glob('**/*.conf')]
Out[20]:
['ntp-restrict.conf',
 'dnsextd.conf',
 'syslog.conf',
```

If you want a list of conf files in the tree >= 1K:

```
In [23]: [x.name for x in Path('/etc').glob('**/*.conf') if x.stat().st_size > 1024]
Out[23]:
['dnsextd.conf',
 'pf.conf',
 'autofs.conf',
```

Resolving relative paths become easy:

```
In [32]: Path('../Operational Metrics.md').resolve()
Out[32]: PosixPath('/Users/starver/code/xxxx/Operational Metrics.md')
```

Navigating with a Path is pretty clear (although unexpected):

```
In [10]: p = Path('.')

In [11]: core = p / 'web' / 'core'

In [13]: [x for x in core.iterdir() if x.is_file()]
Out[13]:
[PosixPath('web/core/metrics.py'),
 PosixPath('web/core/services.py'),
 PosixPath('web/core/querysets.py'),
```

Answer (score 5):

A recursive implementation

```
import os

def scan_dir(dir):
    for name in os.listdir(dir):
        path = os.path.join(dir, name)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            print path
        else:
            scan_dir(path)
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option.

```
os.scandir(path='.')
```

It returns an iterator of os.DirEntry objects corresponding to the entries (along with file attribute information) in the directory given by path.

*Example:*

```
with os.scandir(path) as it:
    for entry in it:
        if not entry.name.startswith('.'):
            print(entry.name)
```

**Using scandir() instead of listdir() can significantly increase the performance of code that also needs file type or file attribute information**, because os.DirEntry objects expose this information if the operating system provides it when scanning a directory. All os.DirEntry methods may perform a system call, but is_dir() and is_file() usually only require a system call for symbolic links; os.DirEntry.stat() always requires a system call on Unix but only requires one for symbolic links on Windows.

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a long version, with all the options I might need: http://sam.nipl.net/code/python/find.py

I guess it will fit here too:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

def ls(dir, hidden=False, relative=True):
    nodes = []
    for nm in os.listdir(dir):
        if not hidden and nm.startswith('.'):
            continue
        if not relative:
            nm = os.path.join(dir, nm)
        nodes.append(nm)
    nodes.sort()
    return nodes

def find(root, files=True, dirs=False, hidden=False, relative=True, topdown=True):
    root = os.path.join(root, '')  # add slash if not there
    for parent, ldirs, lfiles in os.walk(root, topdown=topdown):
        if relative:
            parent = parent[len(root):]
        if dirs and parent:
            yield os.path.join(parent, '')
        if not hidden:
            lfiles   = [nm for nm in lfiles if not nm.startswith('.')]
            ldirs[:] = [nm for nm in ldirs  if not nm.startswith('.')]  # in place
        if files:
            lfiles.sort()
            for nm in lfiles:
                nm = os.path.join(parent, nm)
                yield nm

def test(root):
    print "* directory listing, with hidden files:"
    print ls(root, hidden=True)
    print
    print "* recursive listing, with dirs, but no hidden files:"
    for f in find(root, dirs=True):
        print f
    print

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(*sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

The one worked with me is kind of a modified version from Saleh's answer elsewhere on this page.

The code is as follows:

```py
dir = 'given_directory_name'
filenames = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,i)) for i in os.listdir(dir)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice one liner to list only the files recursively.  I used this in my setup.py package_data directive:

```
import os

[os.path.join(x[0],y) for x in os.walk('<some_directory>') for y in x[2]]
```

I know it's not the answer to the question, but may come in handy

Answer (score 1):

## For Python 2

```
#!/bin/python2

import os

def scan_dir(path):
    print map(os.path.abspath, os.listdir(pwd))
```

## For Python 3

For filter and map, you need wrap them with list()

```
#!/bin/python3

import os

def scan_dir(path):
    print(list(map(os.path.abspath, os.listdir(pwd))))
```

The recommendation now is that you replace your usage of map and filter with generators expressions or list comprehensions:

```
#!/bin/python

import os

def scan_dir(path):
    print([os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir(path)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will list directories and the files within the dir

```
def print_directory_contents(sPath):
        import os                                       
        for sChild in os.listdir(sPath):                
            sChildPath = os.path.join(sPath,sChild)
            if os.path.isdir(sChildPath):
                print_directory_contents(sChildPath)
            else:
                print(sChildPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import modules
import os

_CURRENT_DIR = '.'


def rec_tree_traverse(curr_dir, indent):
    "recurcive function to traverse the directory"
    #print "[traverse_tree]"

    try :
        dfList = [os.path.join(curr_dir, f_or_d) for f_or_d in os.listdir(curr_dir)]
    except:
        print "wrong path name/directory name"
        return

    for file_or_dir in dfList:

        if os.path.isdir(file_or_dir):
            #print "dir  : ",
            print indent, file_or_dir,"\\"
            rec_tree_traverse(file_or_dir, indent*2)

        if os.path.isfile(file_or_dir):
            #print "file : ",
            print indent, file_or_dir

    #end if for loop
#end of traverse_tree()

def main():

    base_dir = _CURRENT_DIR

    rec_tree_traverse(base_dir," ")

    raw_input("enter any key to exit....")
#end of main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This question already has a perfectly good answer, there is no need to answer again

Answer (score 0):

FYI Add a filter of extension or ext file
    import os

```
path = '.'
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    # print path to all filenames with extension py.
    for filename in filenames:
        fname_path = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        fext = os.path.splitext(fname_path)[1]
        if fext == '.py':
            print fname_path
        else:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If figured I'd throw this in.  Simple and dirty way to do wildcard searches.

```
import re
import os

[a for a in os.listdir(".") if re.search("^.*\.py$",a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one line Pythonic version:

```
import os
dir = 'given_directory_name'
filenames = [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),dir,i) for i in os.listdir(dir)]
```

This code lists the full path of all files and directories in the given directory name.

Comment: Thanks Saleh, but your code didn't worked fully, and the one worked was modified as follows:

'dir = 'given_directory_name'
filenames = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dir,i)) for i in os.listdir(dir)]'

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. This is a neat way I came across if you are on a liunx machine.

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(["ls", "/"]).decode("utf8"))
```

Comment: This is *hugely* inefficient as well as error-prone. Python knows full well how to traverse a directory listing and [you should not use `ls` in scripts ever anyway.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
list_output_files = [os.getcwd()+"\\"+f for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd())]
```

Comment: how can I apply this to a specific folder?