# Getting a list of all subdirectories in the current directory

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

Is there a way to return a list of all the subdirectories in the current directory in Python?

I know you can do this with files, but I need to get the list of directories instead.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html?highlight=os#os.listdir

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir

Comment: If you are looking for a pathlib solution do `[f for f in data_path.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]` credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228436/1601580. this gives you as strings folder names. Somehow it also excludes `.` and `..` thank god. The Glob solution is worthwhile too: `glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*/")`.

Answer (score 936, accepted):

Do you mean immediate subdirectories, or every directory right down the tree?

Either way, you could use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to do this:

```
os.walk(directory)
```

will yield a tuple for each subdirectory. Ths first entry in the 3-tuple is a directory name, so

```
[x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]
```

should give you all of the subdirectories, recursively.

Note that the second entry in the tuple is the list of child directories of the entry in the first position, so you could use this instead, but it's not likely to save you much.

However, you could use it just to give you the immediate child directories:

```
next(os.walk('.'))[1]
```

Or see the other solutions already posted, using [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [`os.path.isdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir), including those at "[How to get all of the immediate subdirectories in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800197/get-all-of-the-immediate-subdirectories-in-python)".

Comment: Such a clean and nice answer. Thank you. I wasn't familiar with next() and thought this link can be helpful to whoever in similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733004/python-next-function

Comment: For anyone concerned about performance differences between `os.walk` and `os.listdir`+`os.path.isdir` solutions: I just tested on a directory with 10,000 subdirectories (with millions of files in the hierarchy below) and the performance differences are negligible. `os.walk`: "10 loops, best of 3: 44.6 msec per loop" and `os.listdir`+`os.path.isdir`: "10 loops, best of 3: 45.1 msec per loop"

Comment: @kevinmicke try this performance test on a network drive, I think you'll find that the performance is rather significant in that case.

Comment: @UKMonkey I'm sure you're right that a use case like that could have a significant difference.

Comment: @UKMonkey: Actually, in 3.4 and earlier they should be roughly equivalent, and in 3.5 and higher `os.walk` should *beat* `os.listdir`+`os.path.isdir`, *especially* on network drives. Reasons: 1) `os.walk` is lazy; if you do `next(os.walk('.'))[1]` it performs a single directory listing & categorizing by dir/non-dir, and then goes away. The cost of setting up the generator is non-zero, but it's utterly unrelated to the cost of file system access. 2) As of 3.5, `os.walk` is implemented via `os.scandir`, which doesn't require per-entry `stat` calls to categorize dir/non-dir (aside from symlinks)…

Comment: …so, ignoring the case of symlinks, `os.walk` effectively requires just a single round trip to the storage medium to get the information on the whole directory (in practice, it's usually a buffered-by-blocks implementation under the hood, so a huge directory might require a number of round trips based on the number of entries divided by a large divisor, but `os.listdir`, implemented using the same system calls, does the same), while `os.listdir`+`os.path.isdir` pays that initial cost plus a per-entry `stat` system call.

Comment: `os.walk` will lose to properly written `os.scandir` usage (e.g. `[e.path for e in os.scandir('.') if e.is_dir()]` which is about as minimalist as you can get), but only because it has some extra overhead from the wrapping to allow recursion and separately store the non-dir `list`, neither of which gets used; it performs no additional system call work, so network drive or not, the biggest part of the expense (drive latency, and to a lesser extent, system call overhead) is still cheaper than `os.listdir`+`os.path.isdir` from 3.5 onwards.

Answer (score 327):

You could just use `glob.glob`

```
from glob import glob
glob("/path/to/directory/*/", recursive = True)
```

Don't forget the trailing `/` after the `*`.

Comment: Nice. Simple. Only, it leaves the trailing `/` in the names

Comment: If you cannot assume `/` to be the folder separator, do this: `glob(os.path.join(path_to_directory, "*", ""))`

Comment: This doesn't work for subdirectories! To use glob here's the complete answer: [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Comment: to make glob recursive you can just add the following argument `recursive=True`

Comment: does not work for subdirectories

Comment: with 2* it work for subdirectories: glob("/path/to/directory/**/", recursive = True)

Answer (score 323):

Much nicer than the above, because you don't need several os.path.join() and you will get the full path directly (if you wish), you can do this in **Python 3.5** and above.

```
subfolders = [ f.path for f in os.scandir(folder) if f.is_dir() ]
```

This will give the complete path to the subdirectory.
If you only want the name of the subdirectory use `f.name` instead of `f.path`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir

---

Slightly OT: In case you need **all subfolder recursively** and/or **all files recursively**, have a look at this function, that is faster than `os.walk` & `glob` and will return a list of all subfolders as well as all files inside those (sub-)subfolders: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803793/2441026

In case you want only **all subfolders recursively**:

```
def fast_scandir(dirname):
    subfolders= [f.path for f in os.scandir(dirname) if f.is_dir()]
    for dirname in list(subfolders):
        subfolders.extend(fast_scandir(dirname))
    return subfolders
```

Returns a list of all subfolders with their full paths. This again is faster than `os.walk` and a lot faster than `glob`.

---

**An analysis of all functions**

tl;dr:
- If you want to get all *immediate* subdirectories for a folder use `os.scandir`.
- If you want to get *all* subdirectories, even *nested* ones, use `os.walk` or - slightly faster - the `fast_scandir` function above.
- Never use `os.walk` for only top-level subdirectories, as it can be hundreds(!) of times slower than `os.scandir`.

- If you run the code below, make sure to run it once so that your OS will have accessed the folder, discard the results and run the test, otherwise results will be screwed.
- You might want to mix up the function calls, but I tested it, and it did not really matter.
- All examples will give the full path to the folder. The pathlib example as a (Windows)Path object.
- The first element of `os.walk` will be the base folder. So you will not get only subdirectories. You can use `fu.pop(0)` to remove it.
- **None of the results will use natural sorting**. This means results will be sorted like this: 1, 10, 2. To get *natural sorting* (1, 2, 10), please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48030307/2441026

**Results**:

```
os.scandir      took   1 ms. Found dirs: 439
os.walk         took 463 ms. Found dirs: 441 -> it found the nested one + base folder.
glob.glob       took  20 ms. Found dirs: 439
pathlib.iterdir took  18 ms. Found dirs: 439
os.listdir      took  18 ms. Found dirs: 439
```

Tested with W7x64, Python 3.8.1.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 3


import time
import os
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path


directory = r"<insert_folder>"
RUNS = 1


def run_os_walk():
    a = time.time_ns()
    for i in range(RUNS):
        fu = [x[0] for x in os.walk(directory)]
    print(f"os.walk\t\t\ttook {(time.time_ns() - a) / 1000 / 1000 / RUNS:.0f} ms. Found dirs: {len(fu)}")


def run_glob():
    a = time.time_ns()
    for i in range(RUNS):
        fu = glob(directory + "/*/")
    print(f"glob.glob\t\ttook {(time.time_ns() - a) / 1000 / 1000 / RUNS:.0f} ms. Found dirs: {len(fu)}")


def run_pathlib_iterdir():
    a = time.time_ns()
    for i in range(RUNS):
        dirname = Path(directory)
        fu = [f for f in dirname.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]
    print(f"pathlib.iterdir\ttook {(time.time_ns() - a) / 1000 / 1000 / RUNS:.0f} ms. Found dirs: {len(fu)}")


def run_os_listdir():
    a = time.time_ns()
    for i in range(RUNS):
        dirname = Path(directory)
        fu = [os.path.join(directory, o) for o in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, o))]
    print(f"os.listdir\t\ttook {(time.time_ns() - a) / 1000 / 1000 / RUNS:.0f} ms. Found dirs: {len(fu)}")


def run_os_scandir():
    a = time.time_ns()
    for i in range(RUNS):
        fu = [f.path for f in os.scandir(directory) if f.is_dir()]
    print(f"os.scandir\t\ttook {(time.time_ns() - a) / 1000 / 1000 / RUNS:.0f} ms.\tFound dirs: {len(fu)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_os_scandir()
    run_os_walk()
    run_glob()
    run_pathlib_iterdir()
    run_os_listdir()
```

Comment: it would be nice if you mention early on your question where you are substituting the different functions you profile. Regardless, impressive you spent the time doing this. Good job. I personally prefer using a single library so I liked `using `pathlib` as follows `[f for f in p.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]``

Comment: I have 50 subdirectories, each with thousands of subdirectories. I just tried running `fast_scandir` and it's taking over an hour. Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Comment: `for dirname in list(subfolders):` that `list` is superfluous I believe. It wouldn't even do a copy, right?

Comment: os.scandir(folder) will fail completely if you don't have permissions or hit any other exception while it scans; this is unreliable and not a viable solution when you must return all directories except those you can't access. There doesn't seem to be a way around issue which makes os.scandir pretty unreliable and therefore largely useless IMO.

Answer (score 215):

```
import os

d = '.'
[os.path.join(d, o) for o in os.listdir(d) 
                    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d,o))]
```

Comment: note that in this approach you need to care of abspath-issues if not executed on '.'

Comment: Just a heads up, if you are not using the cwd ('.'), this will not work unless you do an `os.path.join` on `o` to get the full path, otherwise `isdir(0)` will always return false

Comment: It appears that the post has been updated with fixes for the two mentioned issues above.

Comment: To avoid calling `os.path.join` twice, you can first join and then filter the list using `os.path.isdir`:

`filter(os.path.isdir, [os.path.join(d, o) for o in os.listdir(d)])`

Comment: Using pathlib with `[f for f in data_path.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]` or glob is much simpler and easier to read: `glob.glob("/path/to/directory/*/")`.

Answer (score 87):

Python 3.4 introduced [the `pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#) into the standard library, which provides an object oriented approach to handle filesystem paths:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('./')

# All subdirectories in the current directory, not recursive.
[f for f in p.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]
```

To recursively list all subdirectories, [path globbing can be used with the `**` pattern.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

```
# This will also include the current directory '.'
list(p.glob('**'))
```

---

Note that a single `*` as the glob pattern would include both files and directories non-recursively. To get only directories, a trailing `/` can be appended but this only works when using the glob library directly, not when using glob via pathlib:

```
import glob

# These three lines return both files and directories
list(p.glob('*'))
list(p.glob('*/'))
glob.glob('*')

# Whereas this returns only directories
glob.glob('*/')
```

So `Path('./').glob('**')` matches the same paths as `glob.glob('**/', recursive=True)`.

Pathlib is also available on Python 2.7 via [the pathlib2 module on PyPi.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/)

Comment: To iterate over the list of subdirectories, here is a nice, clean syntax: `for f in filter(Path.is_dir, p.iterdir()):`

Comment: Are you sure you need two stars for your glob solution? is `gloab(*/)` not sufficient? Regardless, fabulous answer, specially for your clean use of `pathlib`. It would be nice to comment if it also allows recursion, though from the title of the question that's not needed and future readers should read the docs you link.

Comment: Thank you @CharlieParker! I updated my answer with details about recursion and using a trailing slash (including noting that trailing slashes are not necessary when using `**` with pathlib's glob. Regarding, using a single asterisk, this would match files and directories non-recursively.

Comment: `glob.glob('**/', recursive=True)` won't include hidden directories, but `Path('./').glob('**')` does

Comment: might add a `sorted()` at the start, so that the returned list is sorted...might or might not be useful depending on use case

Answer (score 44):

If you need a recursive solution that will find all the subdirectories in the subdirectories, use walk as proposed before.

If you only need the current directory's child directories, combine `os.listdir` with `os.path.isdir`

Comment: using `pathlib` is simpler: `[f for f in p.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]`

Comment: @CharlieParker: this answer predated `pathlib` by a few years.

Comment: Why not write the full answer in one line?

Answer (score 35):

#### Listing Out only directories

```
print("\nWe are listing out only the directories in current directory -")
directories_in_curdir = list(filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(os.curdir)))
print(directories_in_curdir)
```

#### Listing Out only files in current directory

```
files = list(filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(os.curdir)))
print("\nThe following are the list of all files in the current directory -")
print(files)
```

Comment: Did not work on mac OS. I think that the problem is that os.listdir returns only the name of the directory and not the full path but os.path.isdir only returns True if the full path is a directory.

Comment: This works outside of the current directory if you modify the line slightly:
subdirs = filter(os.path.isdir, [os.path.join(dir,x) for x in os.listdir(dir)])

Comment: nice job by avoiding to define lambda functions and just passing the functions directly.

Comment: Luckily as a workaround you can just call `isdir` outside the filter chain on Mac OS X.

Comment: Worked on m1 Mac as of 2023. Thank you!

Answer (score 29):

I prefer using filter (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter), but this is just a matter of taste.

```
d='.'
filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)), os.listdir(d))
```

Comment: using `pathlib` is simpler: `[f for f in p.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]`

Answer (score 25):

Implemented this using python-os-walk. (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/python-os-walk/)

```
import os

print("root prints out directories only from what you specified")
print("dirs prints out sub-directories from root")
print("files prints out all files from root and directories")
print("*" * 20)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/var/log"):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
```

Comment: using `pathlib` is simpler: `[f for f in p.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]`

Answer (score 18):

You can get the list of subdirectories (and files) in Python 2.7 using os.listdir(path)

```
import os
os.listdir(path)  # list of subdirectories and files
```

Comment: This includes files too.

Comment: The name is confusing as 'dir' does not refer to the objects forming the list but to the container directory. Please check your one-line answers, for beginners it is very tempting to select them.

Comment: Beware of that `os.listdir` lists contents of directory including files.

Answer (score 14):

Since I stumbled upon this problem using Python 3.4 and Windows UNC paths, here's a variant for this environment:

```
from pathlib import WindowsPath

def SubDirPath (d):
    return [f for f in d.iterdir() if f.is_dir()]

subdirs = SubDirPath(WindowsPath(r'\\file01.acme.local\home$'))
print(subdirs)
```

Pathlib is new in Python 3.4 and makes working with paths under different OSes much easier:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 14):

Although this question is answered a long time ago. I want to recommend to use the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) module since this is a robust way to work on Windows and Unix OS.

So to get all paths in a specific directory including subdirectories:

```
from pathlib import Path
paths = list(Path('myhomefolder', 'folder').glob('**/*.txt'))

# all sorts of operations
file = paths[0]
file.name
file.stem
file.parent
file.suffix
```

etc.

Answer (score 12):

Copy paste friendly in `ipython`:

```
import os
d='.'
folders = list(filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)), os.listdir(d)))
```

Output from `print(folders)`:

```
['folderA', 'folderB']
```

Comment: What is X in this case?

Comment: @AbhishekParikh `x` is the item from the list created by `os.listdir(d)` because `listdir` will return files and folders he is using the `filter` command with `os.path.isdir` to filter any files out from the list.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks for the tips, guys. I ran into an issue with softlinks (infinite recursion) being returned as dirs. Softlinks? We don't want no stinkin' soft links! So...

This rendered just the dirs, not softlinks:

```
>>> import os
>>> inf = os.walk('.')
>>> [x[0] for x in inf]
['.', './iamadir']
```

Comment: What is `[x[0] for x in inf]` called in python so I could look it up?

Comment: @shinzou  That's a list comprehension. Super useful. Also look up dict comprehensions.

Answer (score 10):

Here are a couple of simple functions based on @Blair Conrad's example -

```
import os

def get_subdirs(dir):
    "Get a list of immediate subdirectories"
    return next(os.walk(dir))[1]

def get_subfiles(dir):
    "Get a list of immediate subfiles"
    return next(os.walk(dir))[2]
```

Comment: did not work. Reports "StopIteration"

Answer (score 10):

This is how I do it.

```
    import os
    for x in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
        if os.path.isdir(x):
            print(x)
```

Comment: It does not works. I guess in x you have to provide complete path to check using isdir()

Comment: You're probably having trouble with os.getcwd(); Essentially, what you can do is you can get the absolute path and use that instead.

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

Comment: using os,pat.join() worked for me. Because it helped to get full path of subdirectory.

Answer (score 9):

Building upon Eli Bendersky's solution, use the following example:

```
import os
test_directory = <your_directory>
for child in os.listdir(test_directory):
    test_path = os.path.join(test_directory, child)
    if os.path.isdir(test_path):
        print test_path
        # Do stuff to the directory "test_path"
```

where `<your_directory>` is the path to the directory you want to traverse.

Answer (score 7):

With full path and accounting for path being `.`, `..`, `\\`, `..\\..\\subfolder`, etc:

```
import os, pprint
pprint.pprint([os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path), x[0]) \
    for x in os.walk(os.path.abspath(path))])
```

Answer (score 7):

**The easiest way:**

```
from pathlib import Path
from glob import glob

current_dir = Path.cwd()
all_sub_dir_paths = glob(str(current_dir) + '/*/') # returns list of sub directory paths

all_sub_dir_names = [Path(sub_dir).name for sub_dir in all_sub_dir_paths]
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that easiest, and it's needlessly complicated to mix old-style `glob` module usage with new-style `pathlib` stuff (necessitating constant conversions between `str` and `Path` objects). If you want do demonstrate `pathlib` stuff, stick to `pathlib` where possible; it's frankly prettier anyway, and clearer to boot (vs. your code relying on that trailing `/` to make `glob.glob` not return files, a behavior `Path.glob` doesn't replicate): `all_sub_dir_names = [pth.name for pth in Path.cwd().iterdir() if pth.is_dir()]`

Answer (score 5):

This answer didn't seem to exist already.

```
directories = [ x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(x) ]
```

Comment: This will always return an empty list if you are searching anything other than the current working directory, which is technically what the OP is looking to do, but not very reusable.

Comment: directories = [ x for x in os.listdir(localDir) if os.path.isdir(localDir+x)

Answer (score 5):

I've had a similar question recently, and I found out that the best answer for python 3.6 (as user havlock added) is to use `os.scandir`. Since it seems there is no solution using it, I'll add my own. First, a non-recursive solution that lists only the subdirectories directly under the root directory.

```
def get_dirlist(rootdir):

    dirlist = []

    with os.scandir(rootdir) as rit:
        for entry in rit:
            if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_dir():
                dirlist.append(entry.path)

    dirlist.sort() # Optional, in case you want sorted directory names
    return dirlist
```

The recursive version would look like this:

```
def get_dirlist(rootdir):

    dirlist = []

    with os.scandir(rootdir) as rit:
        for entry in rit:
            if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_dir():
                dirlist.append(entry.path)
                dirlist += get_dirlist(entry.path)

    dirlist.sort() # Optional, in case you want sorted directory names
    return dirlist
```

keep in mind that `entry.path` wields the absolute path to the subdirectory. In case you only need the folder name, you can use `entry.name` instead. Refer to [os.DirEntry](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) for additional details about the `entry` object.

Comment: Actually, the way this is written it will not work on 3.5, only 3.6. To use on 3.5 you need to remove context manager - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401417/with-os-scandir-raises-attributeerror-exit

Comment: This is correct. I could swear I read somewhere that the context manager was implemented in 3.5, but It seems I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5):

using os walk

```
sub_folders = []
for dir, sub_dirs, files in os.walk(test_folder):
    sub_folders.extend(sub_dirs)
```

Comment: This will only add one sub-folder, and not lower level folders within the sub-folders.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone like me who just needed the names of the immediate folders within a directory this worked on Windows.

```
import os

for f in os.scandir(mypath):
    print(f.name)
```

Comment: The results include names of files too, at least on Debian (WSL).

Answer (score 3):

This will list all subdirectories right down the file tree.

```py
import pathlib


def list_dir(dir):
    path = pathlib.Path(dir)
    dir = []
    try:
        for item in path.iterdir():
            if item.is_dir():
                dir.append(item)
                dir = dir + list_dir(item)
        return dir
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('Invalid directory')
```

`pathlib` is new in version 3.4

Answer (score 3):

Function to return a List of all subdirectories within a given file path. Will search through the entire file tree.

```
import os

def get_sub_directory_paths(start_directory, sub_directories):
    """
    This method iterates through all subdirectory paths of a given 
    directory to collect all directory paths.

    :param start_directory: The starting directory path.
    :param sub_directories: A List that all subdirectory paths will be 
        stored to.
    :return: A List of all sub-directory paths.
    """

    for item in os.listdir(start_directory):
        full_path = os.path.join(start_directory, item)

        if os.path.isdir(full_path):
            sub_directories.append(full_path)

            # Recursive call to search through all subdirectories.
            get_sub_directory_paths(full_path, sub_directories)

return sub_directories
```

Answer (score 2):

This function, with a given parent `directory` iterates over all its `directories` recursively and `prints` all the `filenames` which it founds inside. Quite useful.

```
import os

def printDirectoryFiles(directory):
   for filename in os.listdir(directory):  
        full_path=os.path.join(directory, filename)
        if not os.path.isdir(full_path): 
            print( full_path + "\n")


def checkFolders(directory):

    dir_list = next(os.walk(directory))[1]

    #print(dir_list)

    for dir in dir_list:           
        print(dir)
        checkFolders(directory +"/"+ dir) 

    printDirectoryFiles(directory)       

main_dir="C:/Users/S0082448/Desktop/carpeta1"

checkFolders(main_dir)


input("Press enter to exit ;")
```

Answer (score 2):

we can get list of all the folders by using **os.walk()**

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()

pathObject = os.walk(path)
```

this **pathObject** is a object and we can get an array by

```
arr = [x for x in pathObject]

arr is of type [('current directory', [array of folder in current directory], [files in current directory]),('subdirectory', [array of folder in subdirectory], [files in subdirectory]) ....]
```

We can get list of all the subdirectory by iterating through the **arr** and printing the middle array

```py
for i in arr:
   for j in i[1]:
      print(j)
```

This will print all the subdirectory.

To get all the files:

```
for i in arr:
   for j in i[2]:
      print(i[0] + "/" + j)
```

Answer (score 1):

use a filter function `os.path.isdir` over `os.listdir()`
something like this `filter(os.path.isdir,[os.path.join(os.path.abspath('PATH'),p) for p in os.listdir('PATH/')])`

Answer (score 1):

By joining multiple solutions from here, this is what I ended up using:

```
import os
import glob

def list_dirs(path):
    return [os.path.basename(x) for x in filter(
        os.path.isdir, glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lot of nice answers out there but if you came here looking for a simple way to get list of all files or folders at once. You can take advantage of the os offered **find** on linux and mac which and is much faster than os.walk

```
import os
all_files_list = os.popen("find path/to/my_base_folder -type f").read().splitlines()
all_sub_directories_list = os.popen("find path/to/my_base_folder -type d").read().splitlines()
```

OR

```
import os

def get_files(path):
    all_files_list = os.popen(f"find {path} -type f").read().splitlines()
    return all_files_list

def get_sub_folders(path):
    all_sub_directories_list = os.popen(f"find {path} -type d").read().splitlines()
    return all_sub_directories_list
```

Comment: wow, you just saved my life! (figuratively)
I had a few folders but millions of files, and all of the methods described above was taking forever to execute, this is so much faster.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of responses! After reviewing all the suggestions, I filtered out three candidates for listing all the folders in the tree and two methods for listing the immediate folders.

Every folder:

```
dirs_rglob = [x for x in folder.rglob('*') if x.is_dir()]
dirs_walk = [x[0] for x in os.walk(folder)]
dirs_custom = fast_scandir(folder)
```

where `fast_scandir()` is a custom function suggested by user136036, see my code below. I tested the performance with the following Python code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from os import walk,scandir
from time import monotonic

#user136036 custom code:
def fast_scandir(dirname):
    subfolders= [f.path for f in scandir(dirname) if f.is_dir()]
    for dirname in list(subfolders):
        subfolders.extend(fast_scandir(dirname))
    return subfolders

folder = Path('c:/xampp/htdocs/fonts') # Insert your path here 
msg = 'Using {}, seconds: {}, number of folders: {}.\n'

start = monotonic()
dirs_rglob = [x for x in folder.rglob('*') if x.is_dir()]
print(msg.format('Path.rglob', monotonic() - start, len(dirs_rglob)))

start = monotonic()
dirs_walk = [x[0] for x in walk(folder)]
print(msg.format('os.walk', monotonic() - start, len(dirs_walk)))

start = monotonic()
dirs_custom = fast_scandir(folder)
print(msg.format('fast_scandir', monotonic() - start, len(dirs_custom)))
```

As stated by user136036, his custom method is the fastest, but not much compared to `os.walk(folder)`, while `folder.rglob('*')` is really very slow. Since the custom method is not that much faster, I use `os.walk(folder)`, since the latter function has no problems with the Windows operating system for system folders or the Recycle Bin.

If you only need a list of immediate folders, you can use

```
dirs_iter = [ f for f in folder.iterdir()  if f.is_dir()]
dirs_scan = [ f.path for f in os.scandir(folder)  if f.is_dir()]
```

The elapsed times are both very small, with the `folder.iterdir()` method sometimes being slightly faster.

Bottom line: Use `os.walk(folder)` for the entire tree of subdirectories and `folder.iterdir()` or `os.scandir(folder)` for the immediate subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, as it also creates a directory tree;

```
import os
import pathlib

def tree(directory):
    print(f'+ {directory}')
    print("There are " + str(len(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))) + \
    " folders in this directory;")
    for path in sorted(directory.glob('*')):
        depth = len(path.relative_to(directory).parts)
        spacer = '    ' * depth
        print(f'{spacer}+ {path.name}')
```

This should list all the directories in a folder using the `pathlib` library. `path.relative_to(directory).parts` gets the elements relative to the current working dir.

Answer (score 0):

This below class would be able to get list of files, folder and all sub folder inside a given directory

```
import os
import json

class GetDirectoryList():
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.main_path = path
        self.absolute_path = []
        self.relative_path = []


    def get_files_and_folders(self, resp, path):
        all = os.listdir(path)
        resp["files"] = []
        for file_folder in all:
            if file_folder != "." and file_folder != "..":
                if os.path.isdir(path + "/" + file_folder):
                    resp[file_folder] = {}
                    self.get_files_and_folders(resp=resp[file_folder], path= path + "/" + file_folder)
                else:
                    resp["files"].append(file_folder)
                    self.absolute_path.append(path.replace(self.main_path + "/", "") + "/" + file_folder)
                    self.relative_path.append(path + "/" + file_folder)
        return resp, self.relative_path, self.absolute_path

    @property
    def get_all_files_folder(self):
        self.resp = {self.main_path: {}}
        all = self.get_files_and_folders(self.resp[self.main_path], self.main_path)
        return all

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mylib = GetDirectoryList(path="sample_folder")
    file_list = mylib.get_all_files_folder
    print (json.dumps(file_list))
```

Whereas Sample Directory looks like

```
sample_folder/
    lib_a/
        lib_c/
            lib_e/
                __init__.py
                a.txt
            __init__.py
            b.txt
            c.txt
        lib_d/
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
        d.txt
    lib_b/
        __init__.py
        e.txt
    __init__.py
```

Result Obtained

```
[
  {
    "files": [
      "__init__.py"
    ],
    "lib_b": {
      "files": [
        "__init__.py",
        "e.txt"
      ]
    },
    "lib_a": {
      "files": [
        "__init__.py",
        "d.txt"
      ],
      "lib_c": {
        "files": [
          "__init__.py",
          "c.txt",
          "b.txt"
        ],
        "lib_e": {
          "files": [
            "__init__.py",
            "a.txt"
          ]
        }
      },
      "lib_d": {
        "files": [
          "__init__.py"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  [
    "sample_folder/lib_b/__init__.py",
    "sample_folder/lib_b/e.txt",
    "sample_folder/__init__.py",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/lib_c/lib_e/__init__.py",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/lib_c/lib_e/a.txt",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/lib_c/__init__.py",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/lib_c/c.txt",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/lib_c/b.txt",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/lib_d/__init__.py",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/__init__.py",
    "sample_folder/lib_a/d.txt"
  ],
  [
    "lib_b/__init__.py",
    "lib_b/e.txt",
    "sample_folder/__init__.py",
    "lib_a/lib_c/lib_e/__init__.py",
    "lib_a/lib_c/lib_e/a.txt",
    "lib_a/lib_c/__init__.py",
    "lib_a/lib_c/c.txt",
    "lib_a/lib_c/b.txt",
    "lib_a/lib_d/__init__.py",
    "lib_a/__init__.py",
    "lib_a/d.txt"
  ]
]
```

Comment: This code throws an error:    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'  ```AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12328\702766901.py in <cell line: 31>()
     32     #mylib = GetDirectoryList(path="sample_folder")
     33     mylib = GetDirectoryList(os.getcwd())
---> 34     file_list = mylib.get_all_files_folder
     35     print (json.dumps(file_list))```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = "test/"
files = [x[0] + "/" + y for x in os.walk(path) if len(x[-1]) > 0 for y in x[-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

**it's simple recursive solution for it**

```
import os
def fn(dir=r"C:\Users\aryan\Downloads\opendatakit"):  # 1.Get file names from directory
    file_list = os.listdir(dir)
    res = []
    # print(file_list)
    for file in file_list:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir, file)):
                res.append(file)
        else:
            result = fn(os.path.join(dir, file))
            if result:
                res.extend(fn(os.path.join(dir, file)))
    return res


res = fn()
print(res)
print(len(res))
```