# Python's equivalent for Matlab's persistent

Tags: python, decorator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the Python equivalent of static variables inside a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function)

I try to write a recursive function. It iterates over a vector and gives a value which depends upon current value and previous value. In Matlab I can declare a variable as `persistent` inside the function and the value is stored in memory after the function is called, so next call of the function start from the previous values.

This is what i started for simple moving average:

```
def AvgFilter(x):
    if not firstRun:  # checks if runs for first time, i.e. firstRun is empty
        k = 1        # setup initial variables if run for first time
        prevAvg = 0  # prevAvg - the average calculated during last call
        firstRun = 1 # only for initialisation
    alpha = (k-1)/k  
    avg = alpha * prevAvg + (1 - alpha)*x
    prevAvg = avg
    k = k + 1    
    return avg
```

I need the variables `k` `prevAvg` `firstRun` to be remembered between function calls. I read it can be done via decorator, I did try to implement it seting `@counter` before function but not sure how I should implement it. Is decorator the only way (did not find anything else)? and how to write counter function to store my variables? I bit worry that later on with more complicated recursions I will be completely lost with the idea of decorator.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279561/what-is-the-python-equivalent-of-static-variables-inside-a-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to answers of @Thomas Orozco and @jtbandes After a few long days at last I get it working how I wanted. The code together with some testing is:

```
x = [10,2,30,4,50]
class avgFil2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.avg = 0
        self.k = 1.0
    def __call__(self, x):
        alpha = (self.k-1.0)/self.k  
        self.avg = alpha * self.avg + (1 - alpha)*x
        self.k +=1
       return self.avg

def simpleTest(x = x):     
    average = []
    avg = avgFil2()               # new variable and creation of instance (all initialisation)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        print 'input %f' % x[i] 
        print 'before change avg.avg=%f, k=%f' % (avg.avg, avg.k)   
        average.append(avg(x[i])) # class is called here, so all changes going on
        print 'after change avg.avg=%f, k=%f' % (avg.avg, avg.k)  
        print 'The output average is %f' % average[i]

simpleTest()
```

The code is really different from Matlab, but is nice. Important traps are to initialise `k=1.0` to `float` not `k=1` to `int` because `alpha` would be zero as division would evaluate to integer. Another thing, I had to initialise to 'self.k' not 'k' as it was giving the error otherwise. Generators probably work as well, but I like `class` solution.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for [generators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733017/23649)! Generators let you pretend you're just calculating the values one at a time in a loop, but it will actually pause execution and return a value when you call `yield`.

```
def AvgFilter():
    k = 1
    avg = 0
    while True:
        alpha = (k-1)/float(k)
        x = yield avg # yield/return the old average, and get the new input value
        avg = alpha * avg + (1 - alpha)*x
        k = k + 1

f = AvgFilter()
print f.next()
print f.send(1)
print f.send(2)
print f.send(20)
print f.send(20)

# 0
# 1.0
# 1.5
# 7.66666666667
# 10.75
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

- Using an object and storing those variables in the object, reusing the same object between function calls.
- Using global variables (strongly discouraged!)
- Using a generator (see jtbandes' answer)

Here's an example:

```
class AvgFilter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.k = 1
        self.avg = 0

    def run(x):
        alpha = float(self.k-1) / self.k  
        self.avg = alpha * self.avg + (1 - alpha)*x
        self.k +=1
        return self.avg
```

Comment: I could not get it working, as have error `AttributeError: 'AvgFilter' object has no attribute 'avg'`. And after correction had a problem with output as not as expected (int division in python), but the idea is what I needed

Comment: @tomasz74 Yes you're indeed right I'll modify the bits that need it!