# map in Python with multiple arguments, including one with a default value

Tags: python, python-3.x, default

I am using Python3.6 and am trying to figure out ways in which we can use `map` with multiple arguments.

When I run,

```
def multiply(x, y, z):
    return x * y * z

products = map(multiply, [3,6], [1,8], [3,5])
```

`list(products)` returns `[9, 240]` as expected

However, when I specify a default value for z,

```
def multiply(x, y, z = [3,5]):
    return x * y * z

products = map(multiply, [3,6], [1,8])
```

`list(product)` returns

```
[[3, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5],
 [3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  3,
  5]]
```

Why does Python differ in the way it runs `map` in the two scenarios?

Comment: Because `z` is a list..

Comment: Sure, But isn't `z` a list in both scenarios?

Comment: Okay, i'll edit

Comment: @Isaac no, it's *not* a list in both scenarios. It get's passed the elements *inside the list* when you use `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the default value of z during execution with map this happens:

```
3 * 1 * [3,5]
6 * 8 * [3,5]
```

Therefore your output, for map to work as you intend you should explicitly give the list as one of it arguments and in your case the default value of z is not a direct argument of map. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
l=iter([3,5])
def multiply(x, y, z = l):
    return x * y * next(z)

products = map(multiply, [3,6], [1,8])
```

Then `list(products)` would be: `[9, 240]`

**Explanation:**

Your code doesn't work because you're multiplying a number with a list (so basically it will be a list repeated n times), you need to get always the next value, so do `next` to the `iter` of the list

See: [Python: next() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733004/python-next-function)

Comment: This works. Although do you know why the code multiplies `z' to `x*y` when z does not have a default value, and repeats `z`  `x*y` times when z has a default value?

Comment: @Isaac i don't fully understand what you mean, but as you know in the function you're doing something to a __list__ not a __int__  so it basically is `x*y*[3,5]`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should use `reduce` rather than `map`.[This link explain difference between `reduce` and `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934992/main-difference-between-map-and-reduce).Using `reduce` it should be

```
import functools
expected=functools.reduce(lambda acc,current:[acc[0]*current[0],acc[1]*current[1]],([3,6], [1,8], [3,5]))
print(expected) # [9, 240]
```

According to this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).`reduce` is roughly equivalent to:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value
```

Comment: I agree, but if I were to use reduce, I think this might be cleaner:

`expected = functools. reduce(lambda x, y : [z[0]*z[1] for z in zip(x,y)] , ([3,6], [1,8], [3,5]))`

Thanks for the idea.