# is it possible to rerun code and add an code line after the code is done?

Tags: python, csv

Hey its a bit hard to explain, but I will try it.
I have a lot of code, which is working with csv and only one line.
I use `next(csv_reader)` to get only the first line which I call with

```
line = next(csv_reader), line[0] #represents the first line
```

[image]

So with the code I get testpath1 and with `line[1]` I am getting title1
Here ends the whole programm. But I want to continue with the next testpath2 and title2, so I would try to do `next(csv_reader)` and `line = next(csv_reader), line[0] #represents the second line`
This is how I could get thestpath2/3/4 and so one. But how to prevent the StopIteration Execption which comes up when there is nothing to skip? How I count the rows is clear: `row_count = sum(1 for row in csv_reader)` would count my rows. It would be much easier just to rerun the whole code/class but adding this line on top: `next(csv_reader)`. I hope my question is clear. Cheers!

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733004/python-next-function , hopefully that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: next() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733004/python-next-function)