# Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python

Tags: python, file-io

How can I find all the files in a directory having the extension `.txt` in python?

Answer (score 3148, accepted):

You can use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html):

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/mydir")
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    print(file)
```

or simply [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        print(os.path.join("/mydir", file))
```

or if you want to traverse directory, use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/mydir"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: `chdir` is not just unnecessary, it's highly undesirable since a function call is not supposed to irreversibly modify the current working directory. This may cause a lot of downstream errors.

Answer (score 364):

Use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html).

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./*.txt')
['./outline.txt', './pip-log.txt', './test.txt', './testingvim.txt']
```

Comment: Beware that `glob` can't find files **recursively** if your python is under 3.5.  [more inform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Comment: This only finds files in the current top level directory, not within the entire directory.

Answer (score 223):

Something like that should do the job

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            print(file)
```

Comment: Note that this is case sensitive (won't match .TXT or .Txt), so you'll probably want to do if file.lower().endswith('.txt'):

Comment: can't this be abbreviated to something like the following?
for file in os.walk(directory).files:
  if file.endswith ...

Answer (score 220):

You can simply use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib)s [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) <sup>1</sup>:

```
import pathlib

list(pathlib.Path('your_directory').glob('*.txt'))
```

or in a loop:

```
for txt_file in pathlib.Path('your_directory').glob('*.txt'):
    # do something with "txt_file"
```

If you want it recursive you can use `rglob('*.txt')`

> This is like calling Path.glob() with “**/” added in front of the given relative pattern

---

<sup>1</sup>The `pathlib` module was included in the standard library in python 3.4. But you can install back-ports of that module even on older Python versions (i.e. using `conda` or `pip`): [`pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/) and [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/).

Comment: Note that you can also use `rglob` if you want to look for items recursively. E.g. `.rglob('*.txt')`

Comment: what if we want to find all files except precisely those that end in .txt?

Comment: @gota get all files and then exclude the txt files `set(pathlib.Path('.').iterdir()) - set(pathlib.Path().glob("*.txt"))`

Answer (score 163):

Something like this will work:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = '/usr/share/cups/charmaps'
>>> text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt')]
>>> text_files
['euc-cn.txt', 'euc-jp.txt', 'euc-kr.txt', 'euc-tw.txt', ... 'windows-950.txt']
```

Comment: You could use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) on each element of `text_files`. It could be something like `text_files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.txt')]`.

Answer (score 55):

```
import os

path = 'mypath/path' 
files = os.listdir(path)

files_txt = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.txt')]
```

Answer (score 37):

I like [os.walk()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html):

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for f in files:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.txt':
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
            print(fullpath)
```

Or with generators:

```
import os

fileiter = (os.path.join(root, f)
    for root, _, files in os.walk(dir)
    for f in files)
txtfileiter = (f for f in fileiter if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == '.txt')
for txt in txtfileiter:
    print(txt)
```

Answer (score 35):

Here's more versions of the same that produce slightly different results:

#### [glob.iglob()](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html#glob.iglob)

```
import glob
for f in glob.iglob("/mydir/*/*.txt"): # generator, search immediate subdirectories 
    print f
```

#### glob.glob1()

```
print glob.glob1("/mydir", "*.tx?")  # literal_directory, basename_pattern
```

#### [fnmatch.filter()](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter)

```
import fnmatch, os
print fnmatch.filter(os.listdir("/mydir"), "*.tx?") # include dot-files
```

Answer (score 29):

Try this this will find all your files recursively:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("H:\\wallpaper")# use whatever directory you want

#double\\ no single \

for file in glob.glob("**/*.txt", recursive = True):
    print(file)
```

Answer (score 26):

#### Python v3.5+

Fast method using os.scandir in a recursive function.  Searches for all files with a specified extension in folder and sub-folders.  It is fast, even for finding 10,000s of files.

I have also included a function to convert the output to a Pandas Dataframe.

```py
import os
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def findFilesInFolderYield(path,  extension, containsTxt='', subFolders = True, excludeText = ''):
    """  Recursive function to find all files of an extension type in a folder (and optionally in all subfolders too)

    path:               Base directory to find files
    extension:          File extension to find.  e.g. 'txt'.  Regular expression. Or  'ls\d' to match ls1, ls2, ls3 etc
    containsTxt:        List of Strings, only finds file if it contains this text.  Ignore if '' (or blank)
    subFolders:         Bool.  If True, find files in all subfolders under path. If False, only searches files in the specified folder
    excludeText:        Text string.  Ignore if ''. Will exclude if text string is in path.
    """
    if type(containsTxt) == str: # if a string and not in a list
        containsTxt = [containsTxt]
    
    myregexobj = re.compile('\.' + extension + '$')    # Makes sure the file extension is at the end and is preceded by a .
    
    try:   # Trapping a OSError or FileNotFoundError:  File permissions problem I believe
        for entry in os.scandir(path):
            if entry.is_file() and myregexobj.search(entry.path): # 
    
                bools = [True for txt in containsTxt if txt in entry.path and (excludeText == '' or excludeText not in entry.path)]
    
                if len(bools)== len(containsTxt):
                    yield entry.stat().st_size, entry.stat().st_atime_ns, entry.stat().st_mtime_ns, entry.stat().st_ctime_ns, entry.path
    
            elif entry.is_dir() and subFolders:   # if its a directory, then repeat process as a nested function
                yield from findFilesInFolderYield(entry.path,  extension, containsTxt, subFolders)
    except OSError as ose:
        print('Cannot access ' + path +'. Probably a permissions error ', ose)
    except FileNotFoundError as fnf:
        print(path +' not found ', fnf)

def findFilesInFolderYieldandGetDf(path,  extension, containsTxt, subFolders = True, excludeText = ''):
    """  Converts returned data from findFilesInFolderYield and creates and Pandas Dataframe.
    Recursive function to find all files of an extension type in a folder (and optionally in all subfolders too)

    path:               Base directory to find files
    extension:          File extension to find.  e.g. 'txt'.  Regular expression. Or  'ls\d' to match ls1, ls2, ls3 etc
    containsTxt:        List of Strings, only finds file if it contains this text.  Ignore if '' (or blank)
    subFolders:         Bool.  If True, find files in all subfolders under path. If False, only searches files in the specified folder
    excludeText:        Text string.  Ignore if ''. Will exclude if text string is in path.
    """
    
    fileSizes, accessTimes, modificationTimes, creationTimes , paths  = zip(*findFilesInFolderYield(path,  extension, containsTxt, subFolders))
    df = pd.DataFrame({
            'FLS_File_Size':fileSizes,
            'FLS_File_Access_Date':accessTimes,
            'FLS_File_Modification_Date':np.array(modificationTimes).astype('timedelta64[ns]'),
            'FLS_File_Creation_Date':creationTimes,
            'FLS_File_PathName':paths,
                  })
    
    df['FLS_File_Modification_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FLS_File_Modification_Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['FLS_File_Creation_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FLS_File_Creation_Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['FLS_File_Access_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['FLS_File_Access_Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)

    return df

ext =   'txt'  # regular expression 
containsTxt=[]
path = 'C:\myFolder'
df = findFilesInFolderYieldandGetDf(path,  ext, containsTxt, subFolders = True)
```

Answer (score 22):

path.py is another alternative: https://github.com/jaraco/path.py

```
from path import path
p = path('/path/to/the/directory')
for f in p.files(pattern='*.txt'):
    print f
```

Answer (score 22):

To get all '.txt' file names inside 'dataPath' folder as a list in a Pythonic way:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
path = "/dataPath/"
onlyTxtFiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)) and  f.endswith(".txt")]
print onlyTxtFiles
```

Answer (score 19):

Python has all tools to do this:

```
import os

the_dir = 'the_dir_that_want_to_search_in'
all_txt_files = filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.txt'), os.listdir(the_dir))
```

Answer (score 13):

I did a test (Python 3.6.4, W7x64) to see which solution is the fastest for one folder, no subdirectories, to get a list of complete file paths for files with a specific extension.

To make it short, for this task `os.listdir()` is the fastest and is 1.7x as fast as the next best: `os.walk()` (with a break!), 2.7x as fast as `pathlib`, 3.2x faster than `os.scandir()` and 3.3x faster than `glob`.
Please keep in mind, that those results will change when you need recursive results. If you copy/paste one method below, please add a .lower() otherwise .EXT would not be found when searching for .ext.

```
import os
import pathlib
import timeit
import glob

def a():
    path = pathlib.Path().cwd()
    list_sqlite_files = [str(f) for f in path.glob("*.sqlite")]

def b(): 
    path = os.getcwd()
    list_sqlite_files = [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == ".sqlite"]

def c():
    path = os.getcwd()
    list_sqlite_files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith(".sqlite")]

def d():
    path = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    list_sqlite_files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in glob.glob("*.sqlite")]

def e():
    path = os.getcwd()
    list_sqlite_files = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in glob.glob1(str(path), "*.sqlite")]

def f():
    path = os.getcwd()
    list_sqlite_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".sqlite"):
                list_sqlite_files.append( os.path.join(root, file) )
        break



print(timeit.timeit(a, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(b, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(c, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(d, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(e, number=1000))
print(timeit.timeit(f, number=1000))
```

Results:

```
# Python 3.6.4
0.431
0.515
0.161
0.548
0.537
0.274
```

Answer (score 11):

To get an array of ".txt" file names from a folder called "data" in the same directory I usually use this simple line of code:

```
import os
fileNames = [fileName for fileName in os.listdir("data") if fileName.endswith(".txt")]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import os
import sys 

if len(sys.argv)==2:
    print('no params')
    sys.exit(1)

dir = sys.argv[1]
mask= sys.argv[2]

files = os.listdir(dir); 

res = filter(lambda x: x.endswith(mask), files); 

print res
```

Answer (score 6):

This code makes my life simpler.

```
import os
fnames = ([file for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir)
    for file in files
    if file.endswith('.txt') #or file.endswith('.png') or file.endswith('.pdf')
    ])
for fname in fnames: print(fname)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use fnmatch: https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        print file
```

Answer (score 5):

A copy-pastable solution similar to the one of ghostdog:

```
def get_all_filepaths(root_path, ext):
    """
    Search all files which have a given extension within root_path.

    This ignores the case of the extension and searches subdirectories, too.

    Parameters
    ----------
    root_path : str
    ext : str

    Returns
    -------
    list of str

    Examples
    --------
    >>> get_all_filepaths('/run', '.lock')
    ['/run/unattended-upgrades.lock',
     '/run/mlocate.daily.lock',
     '/run/xtables.lock',
     '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock',
     '/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock',
     '/run/network/.ifstate.lock',
     '/run/lock/asound.state.lock']
    """
    import os
    all_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.lower().endswith(ext):
                all_files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return all_files
```

You can also use `yield` to create a generator and thus avoid assembling the complete list:

```py
def get_all_filepaths(root_path, ext):
    import os
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_path):
        for filename in files:
            if filename.lower().endswith(ext):
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) and the upper method. In this way you can find any of the following:

1. Name.**txt**;
2. Name.**TXT**;
3. Name.**Txt**

.

```
import fnmatch
import os

    for file in os.listdir("/Users/Johnny/Desktop/MyTXTfolder"):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file.upper(), '*.TXT'):
            print(file)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one with `extend()`

```
types = ('*.jpg', '*.png')
images_list = []
for files in types:
    images_list.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(path, files)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Functional solution with sub-directories:

```
from fnmatch import filter
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain
from os import path, walk

print(*chain(*(map(partial(path.join, root), filter(filenames, "*.txt")) for root, _, filenames in walk("mydir"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

In case the folder contains a lot of files or memory is an constraint, consider using generators:

```
def yield_files_with_extensions(folder_path, file_extension):
   for _, _, files in os.walk(folder_path):
       for file in files:
           if file.endswith(file_extension):
               yield file
```

Option A: Iterate

```
for f in yield_files_with_extensions('.', '.txt'): 
    print(f)
```

Option B: Get all

```
files = [f for f in yield_files_with_extensions('.', '.txt')]
```

Answer (score 1):

use Python [OS](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module to find files with specific extension.

the simple example is here :

```
import os

# This is the path where you want to search
path = r'd:'  

# this is extension you want to detect
extension = '.txt'   # this can be : .jpg  .png  .xls  .log .....

for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files_list:
        if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
            file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            print file_name
            print file_name_path   # This is the full path of the filter file
```

Answer (score 1):

Many users have replied with `os.walk` answers, which includes all files but also all directories and subdirectories and their files.

```
import os


def files_in_dir(path, extension=''):
    """
       Generator: yields all of the files in <path> ending with
       <extension>

       \param   path       Absolute or relative path to inspect,
       \param   extension  [optional] Only yield files matching this,

       \yield              [filenames]
    """


    for _, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        dirs[:] = []  # do not recurse directories.
        yield from [f for f in files if f.endswith(extension)]

# Example: print all the .py files in './python'
for filename in files_in_dir('./python', '*.py'):
    print("-", filename)
```

Or for a one off where you don't need a generator:

```
path, ext = "./python", ext = ".py"
for _, _, dirfiles in os.walk(path):
    matches = (f for f in dirfiles if f.endswith(ext))
    break

for filename in matches:
    print("-", filename)
```

If you are going to use matches for something else, you may want to make it a list rather than a generator expression:

```
    matches = [f for f in dirfiles if f.endswith(ext)]
```