# CSV file reading limit

Tags: python, file

For example I have 500 CSV files in my local directory and I want to manipulate data in those 500 files , reading data from each file one by one and writing it on a new CSV file. I know there is a parameter glob in python we use for reading more then one CSV files. Is there any limit on the maximum number of CSV files we can read using Python scripting ?

Comment: There is no "parameter glob". There is module `glob`. There is no limit on the number of files you can process. There is limit on the number of files you can keep opened at the same time. Do not open all files at once and close them when you do not need them anymore.

Comment: The limit is around 10,000 so you should be fine

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675301/limitation-to-pythons-glob

Comment: Assuming you use Windows, this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870173/is-there-a-limit-on-number-of-open-files-in-windows

Comment: Alright. Thank You guys for a quick response.  its very helpful.

Comment: How big are the files? You don't necessarily need to have them all open at the same time. You could read them into memory one at a time. Say, a list of 500 lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can open and close as many files as you want, however, there is a limit to how many files you can keep open. If you are on Linux, you can use `ulimit -n 500` to expand how many files you can open at the same time to 500. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774724/why-python-has-limit-for-count-of-file-handles)