# Is there a true way to gradually iterate over a large directory in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't quite understand which function should I use to gradually iterate over files in a directory (non-recursively) without precaching them all in a one huge list.
I checked the documentation of `os.scandir()`, but it doesn't explicitly specify whether or not it loads the entire list into memory at once.

I've also checked the documentation on `.iglob()`, but it was later revealed that it *does* store all the items in memory...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Iterators: What does iglob()'s Iterator provide over glob()'s list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287162/python-iterators-what-does-iglobs-iterator-provide-over-globs-list)

Comment: The issue is that stuff like glob and iglob *do* actually store everything in a list

Comment: No, `iglob` and `os.scandir` returns iterator!!!

Comment: `iglob` documentation suggests `Return an iterator which yields the same values as glob() without actually storing them all simultaneously.` Where do you see that `iglob` stores everything is a list? Perhaps some code might help us understand your issue better.

Comment: @buran It still [stores everything in memory](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04e06e20ee61f3c0d1d7a827b2feb4ed41bb198d/Lib/glob.py#L177).

Comment: This is for a single list, the advantages of `iglob` is where there are multiple directories being traversed.

Comment: @WillDereham, you are joking, right? It's explicitly written in the docs for `iglob` - _without actually storing them all simultaneously_

Comment: Read also https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Comment: @buran If you actually read the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04e06e20ee61f3c0d1d7a827b2feb4ed41bb198d/Lib/glob.py), on [line 177](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/04e06e20ee61f3c0d1d7a827b2feb4ed41bb198d/Lib/glob.py#L177) you will see the *generator* of filenames within a *single* directory is converted to a list, the advantage of `iglob` being when using recursive (`**`) patterns. However the question is specifically talking about listing files *non-recursively*.

Comment: It looks to me like a weakness in that cpython implementation. I think it should `yield from it` rather than `return list(it)` but that is just a quick glance at the code path if `iglob()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [PEP 471 - os.scandir() function](https://peps.python.org/pep-0471/#os-scandir), `os.scandir` will do what you want:

> It returns a generator instead of a list, so that scandir acts as a
> true iterator instead of returning the full list immediately.

It uses the system calls `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` on Windows and `readdir` on POSIX systems to avoid loading the entire list of files into memory.