# How to find all text files with Regex?

Tags: python, glob

Hey there.
I'm using glob.glob function in order to get a list of all .txt files on a path that i provide.
The regex I'm feeding the function as `C:\build\*.txt`, but it works only for the root directory, and I'd like to find all text files in c:\build\, also `c:\build\files\ha.txt` for example.

How is it possible?
Thankss.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that `glob.glob` will accept unix shell wildcards and not regex objects (see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html)).

You might accomplish the feat of getting all `.txt` files from all sub directories by using `os.walk`. A method to give you such a list could be something like this:

```
def get_all_txts_on_dir(path):
    import os
    ret = []
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.txt'):
                ret.append(name)
    return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob` doesn't use regular expressions, it has a much simpler set of rules.

An alternative would be to use `os.walk()` and perform the title matching yourself with a regular expression.