# How to get all the files exceeding certain size and deleting them

Tags: linux, delete-file

1. I am looking for a linux command to
   get all the files exceeding a
   certain size from the current
   directory and its sub-directories.
2. Whats the easiest way to delete all these files?

Comment: Also see [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Similar to the exec rm answer, but doesn't need a process for each found file:

```
find . -size +100k -delete
```

Answer (score 16):

One-liner:

```
find . -size +100k -exec rm {} \;
```

The first part (`find . -size +100k`) looks for all the files starting from current directory (`.`) exceeding (`+`) 100 kBytes (`100k`).

The second part (`-exec rm {} \;`) invoked given command on every found file. `{}` is a placeholder for current file name, including path. `\;` just marks end of the command.

Remember to always check whether your filtering criteria are proper by running raw `find`:

```
find . -size +100k
```

Or, you might even make a backup copy before deleting:

```
find . -size +100k -exec cp --parents {} ~/backup \;
```

Comment: "Remember to always check whether your filtering criteria are proper by running raw find" was very useful (can't be too careful with the unforgiving `rm` in Linux!), so I'm upvoting this.

Answer (score 2):

python is installed on all unix based OS, so why not use it instead of bash ?

I always find python more readable than `awk` and `sed` magic.

This is the python code I would have written:

```
import os
Kb = 1024 # Kilo byte is 1024 bytes
Mb = Kb*Kb
Gb = Kb*Kb*Kb
for f in os.listdir("."):
    if os.stat(f).st_size>100*Kb:
        os.remove(f)
```

And this is the one-liner version with `python -c`

```
python -c "import os; [os.remove(f) for f  in os.listdir('.') if os.stat(f).st_size>100*1024]"
```

And if you want to apply the search recursively, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

In [zsh](http://www.zsh.org):

```
ls -l *(Lk+100)   # list file size greater than 100kb
```

so:

```
rm *(Lk+100)
```

More zsh goodness [here](http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/tips/zshtips.html).

Comment: This is not recursive. Use `**/*(.Lk+100)`  #The dot exclude directories, whose size is irrelevant (and spurious when seeking for small files).