# fnmatch and recursive path match with `**`

Tags: python, glob, fnmatch

Is there any built-in or straightforward way to match paths recursively with double asterisk, e.g. like [zsh](http://lorenzod8n.wordpress.com/2007/05/10/recursive-globbing-in-zsh/) does?

For example, with

```
path = 'foo/bar/ham/spam/eggs.py'
```

I can use [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) to test it with

```
fnmatch(path, 'foo/bar/ham/*/*.py'
```

Although, I would like to be able to do:

```
fnmatch(path, 'foo/**/*.py')
```

I know that fnmatch [maps its pattern to regex](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/fnmatch.py), so in the words case I can roll my own fnmatch with additional `**` pattern, but maybe there is an easier way

Comment: Something like `glob.glob`?

Comment: Here's a fork that allows fnmatch * and ** https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywildcard

Comment: You may want to check out my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400344/5030772). It gives a slightly modified version of `fnmatch.translate()` that supports `**` wildcards, and prevents `*` from matching across directory boundaries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into fnmatch source code closely, it internally converts the pattern to a regular expression, mapping `*` into `.*` (and not `[^/]*` or similar) and thus does not care anything for directory separators `/` - unlike UNIX shells:

```
while i < n:
    c = pat[i]
    i = i+1
    if c == '*':
        res = res + '.*'
    elif c == '?':
        res = res + '.'
    elif c == '[':
        ...
```

Thus

```
>>> fnmatch.fnmatch('a/b/d/c', 'a/*/c')
True
>>> fnmatch.fnmatch('a/b/d/c', 'a/*************c')
True
```

Comment: A trap with that is that `foo/**/bar` will glob `foo/bar`, but `foo/.*/bar` won't match it. You can work around it by substituting `**/` in the original glob, converting to a regex (`fnmatch.translate`), then replacing your placeholder by `(.*/)*` which seems to be the semantics of `**/`.

Answer (score 8):

For an fnmatch variant that works on paths, you can use a library called [wcmatch](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/#globglobmatch) which implements a `globmatch` function that matches a path with the same logic that `glob` crawls a filesystem with. You can control the enabled features with flags, in this case, we enable `GLOBSTAR` (using `**` for recursive directory search).

```
>>> from wcmatch import glob
>>> glob.globmatch('some/file/path/filename.txt', 'some/**/*.txt', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR)
True
```

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I was looking fr :)

Comment: Glad to see people discovering the library as useful :). I put in a lot of time developing it.

Comment: Keep up the good work, i'm an opensource author/maintainer too :)

Answer (score 3):

If you can live without using an os.walk loop, try:

[glob2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glob2)

[formic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/formic)

I personally use glob2:

```
import glob2
files = glob2.glob(r'C:\Users\**\iTunes\**\*.mp4')
```

## Addendum:

As of Python 3.5, the native [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) module supports recursive pattern matching:

```
import glob
files = glob.iglob(r'C:\Users\**\iTunes\**\*.mp4', recursive=True)
```

Comment: The question is about working with path (which may be virtual), while glob is working with scanning real filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet adds compatibility for **

```py
import re
from functools import lru_cache
from fnmatch import translate as fnmatch_translate


@lru_cache(maxsize=256, typed=True)
def _compile_fnmatch(pat):
    # fixes fnmatch for recursive ** (for compatibilty with Path.glob)
    pat = fnmatch_translate(pat)
    pat = pat.replace('(?s:.*.*/', '(?s:(^|.*/)')
    pat = pat.replace('/.*.*/', '.*/')
    return re.compile(pat).match


def fnmatch(name, pat):
    return _compile_fnmatch(str(pat))(str(name)) is not None
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work in py3.9. Appears that fnmatch now filters consecutive star characters out