# How to match python paths against recursive glob patterns

Tags: python, glob

I would like to filter a list of linux-style relative paths using `glob` expressions which may contain `**`.

For example:

```
+-- pattern.py
+-- dir_a
|   +-- pattern.py
|   +-- dir_b
|   |   +-- pattern.py
```

What I'm looking for:

```
glob_match('*.py', 'pattern.py')                         # -> True
glob_match('*.py', 'dir_a/pattern.py')                   # -> False
glob_match('dir_a/**/*.py', 'dir_a/pattern.py')          # -> True
glob_match('dir_a/*.py', 'dir_a/dir_b/pattern.py')       # -> False
glob_match('dir_a/**/*.py', 'dir_a/dir_b/pattern.py')    # -> True
```

If I'm not wrong, both `pathlib.Path.match` and `fnmatch.fnmatch` do not support `**`, but rather interpret a single `*` as *any character, including slash*, which makes the second and fourth example above give `True`.

I think I can see how to implement this, but I'd be looking for an existing implementation I can rely on :)

Thanks!

**Edit** To clarify, the `glob_match` I'm looking for is the bit of `glob.glob(..., recursive=True)` that does the matching, without the bit that does the filesystem scanning. In other words, the result of `glob_match(pattern, rel_path)` should not depend on `rel_path` pointing to an actual file, or even having access to the filesystem.

- temporarily writing `rel_path` to the filesystem just to run `glob_match` would be a solution but I'd rather not
- I thought about diggin up the [implementation in `glob.glob`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/06653f8d15a8a84ee0f43f739704a9a63c27de54/Lib/glob.py#L41) but since it is written as an iterator that doesn't seem much easier than writing a new `glob_match` from scratch...

Comment: What does `**` mean to you?  It's not clear to me why your third line wins.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob

Comment: just to be a bit clearer - I'm looking for the function `glob_match(pattern, rel_path)` such that `rel_path` is among the results of `glob.glob(pattern, recursive=True)` if and only if `glob_match(pattern, rel_path) == True` (provided `rel_path` exists of course) :)

Comment: It seems like you have everything you need, and have practically provided all of the code of the function you're looking for in your comment.  I don't understand what you're struggling with.  The only missing element I see is that you don't define where the root of your file tree is.  Is the current working directory assumed to be the root of the tree, or do you need to specify the root of the tree somehow?

Comment: You may want to check out my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400344/5030772). It gives a slightly modified version of `fnmatch.translate()` that supports `**` wildcards, and prevents `*` from matching across directory boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching, I found that the [glob.globmatch](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/#globmatch) function in the [wcmatch](https://pypi.org/project/wcmatch/) package does exactly what I was looking for (arguments are reversed compared to the code in my question:

```
print(glob.globmatch('pattern.py', '*.py', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR))
print(glob.globmatch('dir_a/pattern.py', '*.py', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR))
print(glob.globmatch('dir_a/pattern.py', 'dir_a/**/*.py', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR))
print(glob.globmatch('dir_a/dir_b/pattern.py', 'dir_a/*.py', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR))
print(glob.globmatch('dir_a/dir_b/pattern.py', 'dir_a/**/*.py', flags=glob.GLOBSTAR))
```

Leaving the question open in case someone has a solution based on Python's standard library.

Comment: Cool!  Glad you found an answer.  I get it now.