# Why do both fnmatch and glob exist?

Tags: python, match

I already have some clues, but since I couldn't find a clear and concise answer anywhere, I thought it might benefit other people as well.

There are two modules in Python which do file name matching, namely [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) and [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

Among other things, one of the differences between the two is that fnmatch does not treat file names starting with a period as being hidden. However, they still seem to perform relatively similar tasks, which makes me wonder why they're split as two separate modules instead of one with their combined functionality.

Is there a good reason for this split or is it just so for Python historical reasons?

Comment: I'm not very familiar, myself, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29725346/12975140), after `glob` breaks the path apart into directory and filename, it internally goes ahead and analyzes each portion using `fnmatch`.

Comment: `fnmatch()` just matches one file to a pattern and returns a boolean. `glob.glob()` returns a list of all the files that match.

Comment: fnmatch is independent of any filesystem - you could use it with a list of filenames coming from a database, for example.  note that `glob` actually uses `fnmatch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fnmatch()` just matches one filename against the pattern, returning `True` or `False`. If you want a list of matching filenames you need to write your own code that calls `os.listdir()`.

`glob.glob()` matches the pattern against all the names in the directory. It allows wildcards in the directory portions, and it will do the matching at each directory level. And if you use the `recursive=True` option, you can use `**` in the directory portion to have it automatically walk the directory (like `os.walk()`) looking for anything that matches the remainder.

So `glob.glob()` is a higher level convenience function that hides lots of details.

Comment: Can anyone provide some historical context?  Are `glob` and `fnmatch` ancient, and are they considered replaced by newer/better options like `pathlib`?  Or does `pathlib` still use the matching functionality of `fnmatch` under the hood?  Is the `fnmatch` module documentation the official definition of globbing patterns?

Comment: This is all open source, you can easily see what pathlib uses.

Answer (score 0):

`glob()` explores your filesystem while `fnmatch()` does not.

`fnmatch` is used in the `glob` implementation.