# In Python, fastest way to build a list of files in a directory with a certain extension

Tags: python, linux, optimization, recursion, filesystems

In Python on a GNU/Linux system, what's the fastest way to recursively scan a directory for all `.MOV` or `.AVI` files, and to store them in a list?

Comment: Fastest probably involves writing extension to use native code. But do you really want that?

Comment: Even if you don't want to do that, depending on how many files and directories we're talking about, it might be faster to execute the external `find` command than processing the results of `os.walk()`. But if the `os.walk()` solution is fast enough, it is more elegant and easy to understand/edit.

Answer (score 7):

You can use os.walk() for recuresive walking and glob.glob() or fnmatch.filter() for file matching:

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

I'd use os.walk to scan the directory, os.path.splitext to grab the suffix and filter them myself.

```
suffixes = set(['.AVI', '.MOV'])
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for f in filenames:
        if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in suffixes:
            yield os.path.join(dirpath, f)
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution because it can be easily adapted to enforce case-insensitive matching.

Answer (score 4):

Example for a list of files in current directory. You can expand this for specific paths.

```
import glob
movlist = glob.glob('*.mov')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
pattern = re.compile('.*\.(mov|MOV|avi|mpg)$')

def fileList(source):
   matches = []
   for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
       for filename in filter(lambda name:pattern.match(name),filenames):
           matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return matches
```

Comment: The [fnmatch](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch) module only supports very simple glob patterns, so your filter won't work.

Comment: @ekhumoro if it works, symbols ([],.,?, *, ()) are allowed to glob, python test code and see which works

Comment: Your pattern is equivalent to `*.[movMOVaipg()]`. This will match, for example, `*.i`, `*.a`, `*.M`, etc, but _not_ `*.MOV`, `*.avi`, etc. Try it for youself!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the use of `os.walk` and a carefully [reading of its documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk).

This may be a one liner approach:

```
[f for root,dirs,files in os.walk('/your/path') for f in files if is_video(f)]
```

Where in `is_video` you check your extensions.

Answer (score 2):

From Python 3.12 onwards, it is possible to use [`Path.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.walk) of the module `pathlib`.

By using `Path` objects instead of string representation of paths, this module makes easier to combine paths, and it allow to use the property [`.suffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path


suffixes = set(['.AVI', '.MOV'])
files_with_suffix = list()

for root, dirs, files in Path(".").walk():
    for file in files:
        if file.suffix in suffixes:
            files_with_suffix.append(root / file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.x:

```
import os

def generic_tree_matching(rootdirname, filterfun):
    return [
        os.path.join(dirname, filename)
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdirname)
        for filename in filenames
        if filterfun(filename)]

def matching_ext(rootdirname, extensions):
    "Case sensitive extension matching"
    return generic_tree_matching(
        rootdirname,
        lambda fn: fn.endswith(extensions))

def matching_ext_ci(rootdirname, extensions):
    "Case insensitive extension matching"
    try:
        extensions= extensions.lower()
    except AttributeError: # assume it's a sequence of extensions
        extensions= tuple(
            extension.lower()
            for extension in extensions)
    return generic_tree_matching(
        rootdirname,
        lambda fn: fn.lower().endswith(extensions))
```

Use either `matching_ext` or `matching_ext_ci` with arguments the root folder and an extension or a tuple of extensions:

```
>>> matching_ext(".", (".mov", ".avi"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pathlib` for this.

```py
from pathlib import Path

files_mov = list(Path(path).rglob("*.MOV"))
```