# Use Python os.walk to identify a list of files

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, fastest way to build a list of files in a directory with a certain extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625908/in-python-fastest-way-to-build-a-list-of-files-in-a-directory-with-a-certain-ex)

I currently am using os.walk to recursively scan through a directory identifying .MOV files

```
def fileList():
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.mov'):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches
```

How can I extend this to identify multiple files, e.g., .mov, .MOV, .avi, .mpg?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def fileList(source):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(('.mov', '.MOV', '.avi', '.mpg')):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `os.path.splitext`:

```
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
    filenames = [ f for f in filenames if os.path.splitext(f)[1] in ('.mov', '.MOV', '.avi', '.mpg') ]
    for filename in filenames:
        matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
return matches
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pattern = re.compile('.*\.(mov|MOV|avi|mpg)$')

def fileList(source):
   matches = []
   for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
       for filename in filter(lambda name:pattern.match(name),filenames):
           matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
   return matches
```