# Python loop over batch of files

Tags: python, file, loops

I want to loop over a batch of files in order to get 32 images of each sub-directory at a time (I cant load all images due to memory) e.g load img 1-32 of every dir use them and then load img 33-64 then 65-96 etc

My directory:

```
Rootdir
  - dir1
    - img 1
    - img 2
    - img...
  - dir2
    - img 5000001
    - img 5000002
    - img...
  - dir3
    - img 10000001
    - img 10000002
    - img...
```

So I would need to load img1,2,..,32, 5000001,...5000032, 1000001,...10000032 at first loop then img33,34,..,64, 5000033,...5000064, 1000033,...10000064 at second loop

Is there a way to do this properly?

I am trying using os.walk and it allows me to loop over my directory but I don't see how I can adapt this loop to my required 32 batches?

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootdir):
      print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
      for fname in sorted(fileList):
        img_path = os.path.join(dirName, fname)
        try:
          img = load_img(img_path, target_size=None)
          imgs.append(img)
        except Exception as e:
          print(str(e), fname, i)
      #do something on imgs
```

**EDIT**

all of your comment get me stuff like that:

dir1/img1.jpg to dir1/img32.jpg then dir1/img33.jpg to dir1/img64.jpg then 
...

then dir2/img1.jpg to dir1/img32.jpg then dir2/img33.jpg to dir2/img64.jpg then ...

then dir3/img1.jpg to dir3/img32.jpg then dir3/img33.jpg to dir3/img64.jpg :(

What I'm trying to achieve is:

Files of dir1 numero 1 to 32 + files of dir2 numero 1 to 32 + files of dir3 numero 1 to 32 then

Files of dir1 numero 33 to 64 + files of dir2 numero 33 to 64 + files of dir3 numero 33 to 64 in the same loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8625991/use-python-os-walk-to-identify-a-list-of-files

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: os.walk allow me to loop over my directory yes that's what i'm using but I don't see how to loop over every 32 file of my directory

Answer (score 3):

**[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.walk) already returns a generator which will yield a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) values on fly, so you just need to yield the slice of the filenames array in batches of 32.**

---

**This is an example:**

```
import os

# Your root directory path
rootdir = r"Root"

#Your batch size
batch_size = 32

def walk_dirs(directory, batch_size):
    walk_dirs_generator = os.walk(directory)
    for dirname, subdirectories, filenames in walk_dirs_generator:
        for i in range(0, len(filenames), batch_size):
            # slice the filenames list 0-31, 32-64 and so on
            yield [os.path.join(dirname, filename) for filename in filenames[i:i+batch_size]]

# Finally iterate over the walk_dirs function which itself returns a generator
for file_name_batch in walk_dirs(rootdir, batch_size):
    for file_name in file_name_batch:
        # Do some processing on the batch now
        print (file_name)
        pass
```

Comment: again this give me batch of 32 files of one directory one by one. for exemple I have 3 directory kitchen bathroom and bedroom, using your code I get kitchen/img1.jpg to kitchen/img32.jpg and then I get kitchen/img33.jpg to kitchen/img64.jpg, 

I don't want that I want kitchen/img1.jpg to kitchen/img32.jpg + bathroom/img1.jpg to bathroom/img32.jpg + bedroom/img1.jpg to bedroom/img32.jpg in the same loop

Comment: I don't know if what I'm trying to achieve is clear but I need the first files of each directory yield at one time then the second batch of each dir etc

Comment: @HadrienBerthier yeah got the requirement, let me check

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

EDIT: simple counter example

```
counter = 0
for x in mylist:
    # do something with x 
    todo_list.append(x)
    counter += 1
    if counter % 32 == 0: 
        # do something with todo list
        todo_list = [] # empty todo list for next batch
```

Comment: I updated my post I know the existence of os.walk but don't know how to loop on 32 files then 32 next files etc.

Comment: While looping you could keep a counter which does something when it hits 32 and then resets

Comment: it would work to get the first 32 files of each directory but for the files 33-64, 65-96 etc it wouldn't because my loop would re iterate on the first 32.

Comment: I can't load all image in memory so this does not work, I cant make a list of all images.

Comment: You can clear your list every 32 images and load the next 32 no ?

Comment: just set your list to an empty list after you processed your 32 images (see example)

Comment: you don't understand, I need the img 0-32 of every directory then the image 33-64 of every directory etc with your method I get img 0-32 of dir 1 then img 33-64 of same dir etc.  I want to iterate over every directory get the 32 first img from each then the 32 next from each.

Answer (score 0):

What about always using the same img list and process it as soon as you have 32 images?

```
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk('c:\\Java\\'):
      print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
      for fname in sorted(fileList):
        img_path = os.path.join(dirName, fname)
        try:
          img = load_img(img_path, target_size=None)
          imgs.append(img)
          if len(imgs) == 32:
            print("Doing what I have to with current imgs list (add your function here)")
            img = [] # cleaning img list
        except Exception as e:
          print(str(e))
      #do something on imgs
```

if you need to keep track of all the previous lists you can simply copy the list content over.

Let me know if you want that implementation too.

Comment: with this method I will load every 32 image of first directory then the second directory etc I need the 32 image of each directory in my imgs array then the img 33-64 etc

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a way, not the most beautiful but here it is:
I use a set to know which file I already seen and I continue if I'm on it so it doesn't count.

```
number_of_directory = 17
batch_size = 32
seen = set()
for overall_count in pbar(range(data_number // (batch_size * number_of_directory))):
    imgs = []
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootdir):
        count = 0
        for fname in sorted(fileList):
          if fname in seen:
            continue
          if count == batch_size:
            break
          img_path = os.path.join(dirName, fname)
          try:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            img = cv2.resize(img, (img_width, img_height))
            imgs.append(np.array(img))
          except Exception as e:
            print(str(e), fname)
          seen.add(fname)
          count +=1
    #Do something with images
```