# Use a Glob() in VariantDir() einvironment to find files recursively in Python?

Tags: python, scons

How can one make recursive `Glob()` in a `VariantDir()` environment in Python?

The answer from the question <[Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)> will not work, because you need use `Glob()` to get a list of files that is aware of `VariantDir()` environment.

So you need something like:

```py
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('src'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.c'):
    matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

matches = Glob(matches)
```

Will this work?

Comment: This construction `matches = Glob(matches)` does not work, but one can use `matches.append(Glob(os.path.join(root, filename)))` instead of it. Although it does not seem to be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach would work with a minor tweak as follows:

```
import fnmatch
import os

def RecursiveGlob(pathname)
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(pathname):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.c'):
            matches.append(File(os.path.join(root, filename)))

    return matches
```

Notice that I converted it to a File(), since the SCons Glob() function returns Nodes if the "strings" parameter is false.

To be able to handle the VariantDir, etc and to better integrate the functionality with the existing SCons Glob() functionality, you could actually incorporate a call to the existing Glob() function, like this:

```
# Notice the signature is similar to the SCons Glob() signature,
# look at scons-2.1.0/engine/SCons/Node/FS.py line 1403
def RecursiveGlob(pattern, ondisk=True, source=True, strings=False):
    matches = []
    # Instead of using os.getcwd() consider passing-in a path
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        cwd = Dir(root)
        # Glob() returns a list, so using extend() instead of append()
        # The cwd param isnt documented, (look at the code) but its 
        # how you tell SCons what directory to look in.
        matches.extend(Glob(pattern, ondisk, source, strings, cwd))

    return matches
```

You could take it one step further and do the following:

```
def MyGlob(pattern, ondisk=True, source=True, strings=False, recursive=False):
    if not recursive:
        return Glob(pattern, ondisk, source, strings)

    matches = []
    # Instead of using os.getcwd() consider passing-in a path
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        cwd = Dir(root)
        # Glob() returns a list, so using extend() instead of append()
        # The cwd param isnt documented, (look at the code) but its 
        # how you tell SCons what directory to look in.
        matches.extend(Glob(pattern, ondisk, source, strings, cwd))

    return matches
```

Comment: can you tell me how to call this variant of glob? my install is complaining about sixth param. I can see the correct version in source but can't for the life of me invoke it?

Comment: @AdamNaylor, Which version of glob() are you referring to? I dont see which variant of glob in this answer that has 6 parameters. If you want to use one of these variants of glob, then you'll need to define it in your SConstruct.

Comment: When I run your third example, I get: TypeError: Glob() takes at most 5 arguments (6 given)
If I edit line 2055 of my Environment.py (scons v2.3.0) to include the  cwd param it works?!?

Comment: In fact it doesn't appear to honour VariantDir's because if I print 'dirnames' inside the loop it is always empty. Which means it is looking at the VariantDir, not the source dir.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the accepted answer only works if your source directory is `'.'`.

Here is a working example where the source directory is `src` and the variant directory is `build`.

## File layout

```
.
├── include
│   └── sum.h
├── SConstruct
└── src
    ├── dir
    │   └── sum.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

## Files

sum.h

```
#ifndef _SUM_H_
#define _SUM_H_

double sum(const double x, const double y);

#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sum.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Sum of 1 and 2 = " << sum(1., 2.) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

sum.cpp

```
#include <sum.h>

double sum(const double x, const double y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

SConstruct

```
import os

def variantglob(env, pattern, ondisk=True, source=True, strings=False,
                recursive=False):
    matches = []
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(env['SOURCE_DIR']):
        cwd = Dir(os.path.join(env['VARIANT_DIR'],
                               os.path.relpath(root, env['SOURCE_DIR'])))
        matches.extend(cwd.glob(pattern, ondisk, source, strings))
    return matches

# Create Build Environment
env = Environment()

# Customize Environment
env.Replace(VARIANT_DIR='build',
            SOURCE_DIR='src')
env.Append(CPPPATH=['include'])

# Setup Variant Directory
VariantDir(variant_dir=env['VARIANT_DIR'],
           src_dir=env['SOURCE_DIR'], duplicate=0)

# Build the executable
exe = env.Program(os.path.join(env['VARIANT_DIR'], 'example'),
                  variantglob(env, '*.cpp', recursive=True))

# Install the executable
Install('bin', exe)
```

## Build

Just execute `scons` at the top level directory.  This will create a `build` directory and drop all your temporaries there (variant directory), and it will then install the result of the build into the bin folder.

## Run

Execute `bin/example` to see it work.

## Note

This example was tested on linux.

## Why It Works

When building with variant directories you have to specify the path to the source as though it were already sitting in the variant directory, but those directories may not exist *yet*.  This glob function walks the source tree to construct the paths that *will* be in the variant directory, and then globs against those paths.

Comment: This worked for me after hours of trying to get object files to compile in build libs.