# Need the path for particular files using os.walk()

Tags: python, shapefile, os.walk

I'm trying to perform some geoprocessing.  My task is to locate all shapefiles within a directory, and then find the full path name for that shapefile within the directory.  I can get the name of the shapefile, but I don't know how to get the full path name for that shapefile.

```
shpfiles = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(".shp") == True:
            shpfiles.append[x]
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`os.walk` gives you the path to the directory as the first value in the loop, just use `os.path.join()` to create full filename:

```
shpfiles = []
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(".shp"):
            shpfiles.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))
```

I renamed `path` in the loop to `dirpath` to not conflict with the `path` variable you already were passing to `os.walk()`.

Note that you do not need to test if the result of `.endswith() == True`; `if` already does that for you, the `== True` part is entirely redundant.

You can use `.extend()` and a generator expression to make the above code a little more compact:

```
shpfiles = []
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    shpfiles.extend(os.path.join(dirpath, x) for x in files if x.endswith(".shp"))
```

or even as one list comprehension:

```
shpfiles = [os.path.join(d, x)
            for d, dirs, files in os.walk(path)
            for x in files if x.endswith(".shp")]
```

Comment: Just a small addition to the answer. The file tail could be capitalized, eg.: ```test.jpg``` or ```test.JPG```, which would return ```False``` in the statement ```if x.endswith(".jpg"):```. We could use the Python built-in function [```str.lower()```](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to prevent possible _False_ s. With **```if x.lower().endswith(".jpg"):```** we lower the string before the comparison. Thereby, ```test.jpg``` and ```test.JPG``` will return ```True```.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `import glob` ?

```
import glob 

print(glob.glob('F:\OTHERS\PHOTOS\Panama\\mai13*\\*.jpg') )
```

and i get all the jpeg i want, with absolute path

```
>>> 
['F:\\OTHERS\\PHOTOS\\Panama\\mai13\\03052013271.jpg', 
'F:\\OTHERS\\PHOTOS\\Panama\\mai13\\05052013272.jpg', 
'F:\\OTHERS\\PHOTOS\\Panama\\mai13\\05052013273.jpg']
```

Comment: `glob()` only supports a fixed depth of subdirectories, `os.walk()` supports arbitrary depths. See [How can I search sub-folders using glob.glob module in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/14798263#14798263)

Comment: Original question could be interpreted as a single directory.  For those reading this answer who don't require subdirectories (like me), glob is more pythonic because it is more concise and yields a more immediately useful result.

Comment: after 8 years these replies are no longer valid. Glob now supports recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `os.path.abspath(finename)` will work. Please try.

```
shpfiles = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(".shp") == True:
            shpfiles.append(os.path.join(path, x))
```

Comment: No it won't. `abspath` will base the filename of the *current working directory*, which can be a totally different path altogether.