# Loop using os.walk only runs the first cycle

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops, os.walk

I am trying to get the paths of a group of files that I have in a list. The files are in different subfolders. I am using `os.walk` and loops to run through the different files and appending the complete path to a new dataframe to use in a different program. But there is an error in the code that only makes it run the first cycle of the loop.

the code is based on this thread: [Need the path for particular files using os.walk()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16465399/need-the-path-for-particular-files-using-os-walk)

I am using `python3.6` on `MacOS10.14.6`
I am not sure if it matters but the directories are on an external hard drive.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    dir = "/Volumes/dir1/dir2"
    fastafiles = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
    fastafiles_df = pd.DataFrame(fastafiles)

    fasta_paths = []

    for fasta in fastafiles_df[0]:
        #1
        for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(fasta):
                    #2
                    fasta_paths.append(os.path.join(dir, file))
                    #3
```

Running the code will give me 1 entry in `fasta_paths` with only the path of the first file.

If I `print(fasta)` at #1 I get all 3 file names from my dataframe.

If I `print(file)` at #2 I will get only 1 file name
and if I `print fasta_paths` at #3 I will get the path of the first file.

Could someone point out why the loop does not continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error is because of the namespace collapse due to `dir` being is used to denote the root directory as well as the parameter while unzipping and iterating over the `os.walk` generator object. 
Still, keep in mind that `dir` is the name of a Python standard library and try not to use such variable names.

Can you try with the variable names changed?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

root_dir = "/Volumes/dir1/dir2"
fastafiles = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
fastafiles_df = pd.DataFrame(fastafiles)

fasta_paths = []

for fasta in fastafiles_df[0]:
    #1
    for curr_dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(fasta):
                #2
                fasta_paths.append(os.path.join(curr_dir, file))
```

Comment: That indeed solved the problem. I did not realise I used dir incorrectly. Thanks for pointing that out!