# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can anyone tell me why I get this error? The file is in the folder.

```
import os

with open("C:\\Users\\42077\\Desktop\\test\\vystup\\!output.txt", "a")as f:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\42077\\Desktop\\test\\"):
        for path in files:
            if path.endswith(".txt"):
                with open(path, 'r') as file:
                    data = file.readlines()
                    f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(data[2], path))
```

Comment: [Need the path for particular files using os.walk()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16465439)

Answer (score 0):

the `files` `os.walk()` returns is not a list of paths to files it's a list of names (as strings) of files in the directory where `os.walk()` is currently looking (`root`).

```
for path in files:
    if path.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(path, 'r') as file:
```

so at the end here `open()` is given a file name like `example.txt`.
And when `open()` is not given an absolute path it looks from the `current working directory`. Meaning it tries to find this file wherever this python file is located, and promptly gives an error.