# how to open files that match a pattern in a subdirectory

Tags: python

Hello i have a problem finding and opening files in a subdirectory.
I have several different files called for example :
    mouse_1_animal.txt
    mouse_2_animal.txt
    mouse_3_animal.txt

so i want to find all these files in the subdirectory of the working dir and open them and do something with there lines. This is my try:

```
i=1
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root) :
    for file in files :
        if file == "mouse_{0}_animal.txt".format(i) :
            #do something
            i = i + 1
```

but apparently it doesn't find all the files so i'm wondering if it's the way i'm using to find the file that is wrong.

Comment: I'd suggest to get a list of all files which match the pattern and then open them, edit and close one by one.

Comment: It may be easier to use `os.listdir()` in case of a single subdirectory.

Comment: Note that `files` contains the filenames relative to the current `path` where `os.walk` is at that moment; so you'll need to concatenate the directory and file name (`os.path.join()`) to get the full path name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module-in-python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pythonic way:

```
import glob
for f in glob.glob('./subDir/mouse_*_animal.txt'):
    # do_something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import fnmatch
import os
src = 'sourceDirPath'
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'mouse*.txt'):
      #do something
        i = i + 1
```

for older python version you might want to try glob instead of fnmatch

Answer (score 0):

ok i've solvd my problem like this

```
 file_list = []
 for name in glob.glob('./subDir/mouse_*_animal.txt'):
    file_list.append(name)
 for i in range(len(file_list)+1):
     if './subDir/mouse_*_animal.txt'.format(i) in file_list:
        #do something
```

Comment: `glob.glob()` already returns a list of filenames. So you should shorten your code to: `for f in glob.glob('./subDir/mouse_*_animal.txt'): do_something(f)`

Answer (score 0):

I would propose something like this. Create a list of strings from files, join them together and write.

```
import glob


def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read()


data = [read_file(f) for f in glob.glob('file*.txt')]
conc = "\n>>>>>>>\n".join(data)
with open('output', 'w') as f:
    f.write(conc)
```