# How to open files when subdirs name and file names match

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, path

I have file structure like this

```
\dir1
    \subdir1
        -file1.txt
        -file2.txt

    \subdir3
        -file2.txt
\dir2
    \subdir1
        -file1.txt
    \subdir2
        -file2.txt
```

I want to use `dir1` as reference directory and open file in `dir2` when `dir2` `subdirs` names match to that one in `dir1`. So basically open `file1.txt` in both `\dir1\subdir1\file1.txt` and `\dir2\subdir1\file1.txt` and also match the file names as well.

I can walk through the `subdirs` but cannot find the logic to compare them

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(path_to_json) :
    for file in subdirs :
        print (file)
```

How can we do this ?

[how to open files that match a pattern in a subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535254/how-to-open-files-that-match-a-pattern-in-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a path simply by replacing dir1 with dir2 and if there is such a file, then open both files.

```
import os

path = r"C:....dir1"
files_dir1 = []

# We make a list of all files in the directory dir1.

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        files_dir1.append(os.path.join(root, file))

for name in files_dir1:
    name_dir2 = name.replace('dir1', 'dir2', 1)

    # Open files when a file with a new path exists.

    if os.path.isfile(name_dir2):
        with open(name, 'r') as f:
            print(name, f.read())

        with open(name_dir2, 'r') as f:
            print(name_dir2, f.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for file_1 in Path('dir1').rglob('*.*'):
    file_2 = Path('dir2', *file_1.parts[1:])
    if file_2.exists():
        print(str(file_1))
        print(str(file_2))
```

If you only want to go for `txt`-files then change `.rglob('*.*')` to `.rglob('*.txt')`. When there are files without an extension you could do:

```py
for file_1 in Path('dir1').rglob('*'):
    if file_1.is_dir():
        continue
    file_2 = Path('dir2', *file_1.parts[1:])
    if file_2.exists():
        print(str(file_1))
        print(str(file_2))
```

If you only want the files from the first sublevel (exactly one subdir-depth) then you could try:

```py
for file_1 in Path('dir1').glob('*/*.*'):
    file_2 = Path('dir2', *file_1.parts[1:])
    if file_2.exists():
        print(str(file_1))
        print(str(file_2))
```

Comment: I didn't get your solution why you are adding `file_1` path and [1:]. The problem is if the  same file exist in the same subdirs of file_1 and file_2 path. in this case file1.txt exist in both of them so open them and start to do your logic.

Comment: @Alexander I don’t quite understand the question: `file_1.parts[1:]` is the parts of `file_1` path-parts (the parts that are separated by \ or /), except the first part `dir1`. Just out of curiosity: Did it work (worked here)? (If it didn’t, I suspect `dir1` contains path separators.)