# Find absolute path of specific upper directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, os.walk

**Objective:** I am trying to find the absolute path of a specific filename.

**Scenario:** My script is executing from within some (great-great-grand)-parent directory, and my file is somewhere in that same (great...)-parent directory.

**Problem:**

```
E:
├───Directory
│   └───Sub Directory
└───Grandparent Folder
    ├───Parent Directory
    │   └───script.py
    └───Other Parent Directory
        └───MyFile.txt
```

1. The great-parent directory is getting moved around frequently. So the parent directories absolute path is not known.
2. The script is getting moved around a lot within the great-parent directory and changing file levels within that directory, so I can't just use `'../../..'` to get up to the parent directory.
3. The file I'm looking for gets moved around alot within the great-parent directory.

Once I have the absolute path of the parent directory, I can just `os.walk()` around to find my file.

**Attempt:** What I have below works, but I have to imagine this a common enough problem to have a built-in `os` command that I don't know about.

```
import os

parent_folder = 'Grandparent Folder'
search_file = 'MyFile.txt'

# Get absolute path of grandparent directory.
current_path = os.getcwd()
parent_path = current_path.split(parent_folder)[0] + parent_folder

# os.walk() from grandparent down until file is found.
filepath= ''
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_path):
    for file in files:
        if file == search_file:
            filepath = '\\'.join([root, file])
```

Comment: current working directory and script directory don't have to be the same. Which do you want to base your search on?

Comment: script directory

Comment: `os.getcwd()` returns the working directory, use `__file__` to get the script dir.

Answer (score 0):

Try using pythons glob module to find the pathname. You can find details on official documentation. That way even if the directory moves, you can find the path every time.

Comment: Does this help me find my grandparent directory, or just the file once I have the parent directory?

Comment: You can use it to find both as long as you know the script name or the file name (these should be unique else there might be multiple matches)

Comment: @MichaelMolter: You could also use a combination of fnmatch() and glob()
Refer to this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module-in-python

Once you find the file, you can return the working directory.

Comment: I don't think this approach addresses the heart of the problem. It is an easier way to grab the specific file once I find the parent directory, but it in no way helps me find the parent directory?