# How do I strip out all special characters from all filenames?

Tags: python, macos

I need a script to go through all files in all directories and get rid of all special characters, ie: [{!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|]}[{'";:/?.>,<}]. 
Can anyone help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
for fileName in glob.iglob("/home/**/*", recursive = True):
    for character in specialCharacters:
        fileName = fileName.replace(character, "")
```

Something like this? Doesn't get the directories but check out the glob docs, I am sure there is a way to get them.

Comment: that works for a single character in a single directory. I need all the special characters in all directories striped away.

Comment: Why does it only account for a single character? My loop iterates through a list of special characters and removes any that it finds. And with recursive = True it should recursively search the whole directory tree from /home/.

Comment: What I mean by that, is the loop only strips out lets say, "%" from all the files in a single directory. It will not work, for me at least, if i tell it to do, ("%" + "$" + "#" , ""). Or maybee im just doing it wrong.

Comment: Perhaps I used the glob syntax incorrectly in my example, but glob can certainly iterate through all directories under the root directory that you give to it. I have done it before.

Comment: import glob

specialCharacters = ["!" , "@" , "#" , "$" , "%" ,...]
for fileName in glob.iglob("/Desktop/test/**/*", recursive = True):
 for character in specialCharacters:
  fileName = fileName.replace(character, "")  
This is what i have as my code. Not sure where i went wrong, but it does not do anything for me.

Comment: Maybe give the os.walk method a shot then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module-in-python

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a try.