# How to list out file names in a directory based on a pattern

Tags: python

I have a lookup file (*file1.txt*) which has a list of patterns to be searched.

Ex content of *file1.txt*

```
 dtdge_ddgaec
 daew_e2
```

I have to list out the files in a particular directory based on the pattern in file1.txt
  Ex: If a particular directory has the below-mentioned files

```
abdc_dtdge_ddgaec_09030.txt
odad_dwad_dadatge_daece_0869.txt
dadaf_dawa_dpidae_daew_e2_0901.txt
adydyaq_da9dad_dagda_dadge_0730.txt
```

I need to display only the files that match the pattern in *file1.txt*

Output:

```
abdc_dtdge_ddgaec_09030.txt
dadaf_dawa_dpidae_daew_e2_0901.txt
```

In Unix Scripting, I can read *file1.txt* line by line and using ls command i can match the pattern using grep command and display the desired output.

I'm new to Python and unable to find an easy solution.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you read the standard library docs for glob?

Comment: Did you checked this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module-in-python

Comment: I have gone through several google search results but unable to find a solution. So raised a question

Answer (score 2):

You could try a solution using the `glob` module. Something like this, maybe:

```py
import glob
import os.path

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:
    patterns = file1.read().split()

matching_filenames = []
for pattern in patterns:
    matching_filenames += glob.glob(os.path.join(MY_DIR, '*' + pattern + '*'))
```

Comment: Charlie, Thanks for the input. i was able to list out the files  which are matching the pattern in a directory and display the content of it.