# Concatenating multiple dataframes. Issue with datapaths

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation, glob

I want to concatenate several csv files which I saved in a directory `./Errormeasure`. In order to do so, I used the following answer from another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/51118604/9109556

```
filepaths =[f for f in listdir('./Errormeasure')if f.endswith('.csv')]
df=pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv,filepaths))
print(df)
```

However, this code only works, when I have the csv files I want to concatentate both in the `./Errormeasure` directory as well as in the directory below, `./venv`. This however is obviously not convenient. 
When I have the csv files only in the `./Errormeasure`, I recieve the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'errormeasure_871687110001543570.csv' does not exist: b'errormeasure_871687110001543570.csv'
```

Can you give me some tips to tackle this problem? I am using pycharm.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include all `import` lines. Likely you need to map the folder path with file names.

Comment: The csv files are saved in here: `L:\Graduation\Pythonfiles\Errormeasures\venv\Errormeasure`(here I save only the csv files which I want to retrieve.), while the code is situated here: `L:\Graduation\Pythonfiles\Errormeasures\venv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `os.listdir()` only retrieves file names and not parent folders which is needed for `pandas.read_csv()` at relative (where pandas script resides) or absolute levels.

Instead consider the *recursive* feature of built-in `glob` (only available in [Python 3.5+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14798263/1422451)) to return full paths of all csv files at top level and subfolders.

```
import glob

for f in glob.glob(dirpath + "/**/*.csv", recursive=True):
    print(f)
```

From there build data frames in list comprehension (bypassing `map` -see [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)) to be concatenated with `pd.concat`:

```
df_files = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob(dirpath + "/**/*.csv", recursive=True)]
df = pd.concat(df_files)
print(df)
```

---

For Python < 3.5, consider `os.walk()` + `os.listdir()` to retrieve full paths of csv files:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

# COMBINE CSVs IN CURR FOLDER + SUB FOLDERS
fpaths = [os.path.join(dirpath, f) 
            for f in os.listdir(dirpath) if f.endswith('.csv')] + \
         [os.path.join(fdir, fld, f) 
            for fdir, flds, ffile in os.walk(dirpath) 
            for fld in flds  
            for f in os.listdir(os.path.join(fdir, fld)) if f.endswith('.csv')]

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) in for f in fpaths])
print(df)
```

Comment: Great! That did the job. You just have a typo in your second part of code: It has to be `df_files=[pd.read_csv(f)...`

Comment: Sounds good. Glad to help. Whoops! R uses `read.csv` and mistakenly I forgot to code-switch for Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Directory' # use your path
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

list = []

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0)
    list.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Maybe you need to use '\' instead of '/'

```
file = glob.glob(os.path.join(your\\path , '.csv'))
print(file)
```

You can run above codes on for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I get the error `ValueError: No objects to concatenate` now. Do you know a work around for that?

Comment: @jonasa  Do you have duplicate column names? If yes, getting rid of those duplicates will solve your problem.

Comment: @jonasa if the answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: Not within each dataframe. However, the different df's all have the same column names (and I can't change those)

Comment: Change that because they are merging together, or try to remove them implicitly by np.delete(your first header)

Comment: Okay. But I already achieved this with my code I provided above. This already worked but only raised an error, when I saved the files in another map `./Errormeasure`. So I only have to sort out the filepath issue I assume...