# Find All Windows Executable in Linux Directory Recursively

Tags: python

I have a lot of executables (Win32/Dos) inside one of the folders in my Ubuntu machine. 
I want to find them all and print out the paths. I tried:

```
for folder in folders:

    print("Searching: " + str(folder))

    os.chdir(folder)
    for file in glob.glob("**/*.exe", recursive=True):
        print(file)
```

Sadly, this returns no output. What gives?

The folders are under `Documents` directory. Running as root is not an issue.

The question is **not a duplicate** of **"how to find all windows executables recursively"** rather **"why isn't a perfectly correct code that works under Windows misbehaves in linux".**

My hunch is the extension .exe isn't really reciprocated in Linux - maybe I should be looking at file header (or similar) to determine file type.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `folders`? Possibly highly relevant, because did you not even get to see that "Searching.." string?

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes - got that! Folder are under the `Documents` directory. Running as root is not a problem.

Comment: -- I *think* your `os.chdir` is messing things up (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14798263)) but I couldn't get it to work and the first answer in the proposed duplicate worked immediately ...

Comment: @usr2564301 The other solution you posted also doesn't work.

Comment: Your hunch doesn't make sense to me. Linux does not thread .exe files any different than other files. However, be aware that Linux is case-sensitive (so your search won't find any `*.EXE`). Try standard debugging methods to find the problem. For example, print the result of `os.getcwd()` after `os.chdir()` to see if you're really checking the intended directories. Try to (temporarily) search for `'**/*'` instead of `'**/*.exe'` and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with the `file` command:

```py
# os.system for brevity use subprocess instead.
file_type = os.system("file --brief " + os.path.join(folder, current_file))

# check the file name now...
```

or read the first line in byte mode to grab some useful info like magic number in the header.

Comment: yes of course. But i'm not too mutch familiar with glob.