# PurgeCSS: How to define path to all subdirectories?

Tags: glob, postcss, css-purge

The basic [postcss.config.js](https://purgecss.com/plugins/postcss.html#installation) looks like this

```
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    purgecss({
      content: ['./**/*.html']
    })
  ]
}
```

I have a situation where I need to define the path to a folder with nested subdirectories. The only [explanation](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/issues/158) I found was this one:

```
content: [
    // keep only those that you need
    '**/*.html' // will look inside any folder for an .html file
    '!(bar)/**/*.html' // will look inside any folder that is not 'bar'
    '!({bar,foo})/**/*.html' // will look inside any folder that is nor 'bar' nor 'foo'
    '!(bar-*)/**/*.html' // will look inside any folder that does not start with 'bar-'
  ],
  css: [`**/*.css`],
```

...but I want something different: How to define the path to a folder and all his subdirectories (and their subdirectories and so on)?

There is [something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57025016) like

`glob.glob('**/*.txt',recursive=True)`: matches all files ending in '.txt' in the current directory and in all subdirectories

How to set the option `recursive=True` in PostCSS/PurgeCSS?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same situation

Comment: I posted an answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `postcss.config.js` looks like this:

```
const themeDir = __dirname + '/../../';

const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({

    // Specify the paths to all of the template files in your project
    content: [
        themeDir + 'layouts/**/*.html',
        themeDir + 'content/**/*.html',
        'layouts/**/*.html',
        'content/**/*.html',
        // Specify path to own javascript
        themeDir + 'assets/js/**/*.js',
    ],
```