# Python get all the file name in a list

Tags: python, list, file

The problem is to get all the file names in a list that are under a particular directory and in a particular condition.

We have a directory named `"test_dir"`.

There, we have sub directory `"sub_dir_1", "sub_dir_2", "sub_dir_3"`

and inside of each sub dir, we have some files.

```
sub_dir_1 has files ['test.txt', 'test.wav']
sub_dir_2 has files ['test_2.txt', 'test.wav']
sub_dir_2 has files ['test_3.txt', 'test_3.tsv']
```

What I want to get at the end of the day is a list of of the "test.wav" that exist under the "directory" `['sub_dir_1/test.wav', 'sub_dir_2/test.wav']`. As you can see the condition is to get every path of `'test.wav'` under the mother directory.

```
mother_dir_name = "directory"
get_test_wav(mother_dir_name)
returns --> ['sub_dir_1/test.wav', 'sub_dir_2/test.wav']
```

**EDITED**
I have changed the direction of the problem.

We first have this list of file names

```
["sub_dir_1/test.wav","sub_dir_2/test.wav","abc.csv","abc.json","sub_dir_3/test.json"]
```

from this list I would like to get a list that does not contain any path that contains "test.wav" like below

```
["abc.csv","abc.json","sub_dir_3/test.json"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a filtered list of files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225564/get-a-filtered-list-of-files-in-a-directory)

Comment: `glob.glob("*/test.wav")`?

Comment: Thanks. okay so that worked. What if i want to filter out from a list ['sub_dir_1/test.wav','sub_dir_2/test.wav','sub_dir_1/test.txt','someother.file', 'file_4.tsv'] from this list to ['sub_dir_1/test.wav','sub_dir_2/test.wav']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use glob patterns for this. Using `pathlib`,

```
from pathlib import Path
mother_dir = Path("directory")
list(mother_dir.glob("sub_dir_*/*.wav"))
```

Notice that I was fairly specific about which subdirectories to check - anything starting with "sub_dir_". You can change that pattern as needed to fit your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use `os.walk()`:

```
import os

def get_test_wav(folder):
    found = []
    for root, folders, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            if file == "test.wav":
                found.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return found
```

Or a list comprehension approach:

```
import os

def get_test_wav(folder):
    found = [f"{arr[0]}\\test.wav" for arr in os.walk(folder) if "test.wav" in arr[2]]
    return found
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you [How can I search sub-folders using glob.glob module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module)
The main way to make a list of files in a folder (to make it callable later) is:

```
file_path = os.path.join(motherdirectopry, 'subdirectory')
list_files = glob.glob(file_path + "/*.wav")
```

just check that link to see how you can join all sub-directories in a folder.

This will also give you all the file in sub directories that only has .wav at the end:

```
os.chdir(motherdirectory)
glob.glob('**/*.wav', recursive=True)
```