# SCons build all sources files in all directories

Tags: scons

For example:

```
/project/SConstruct
/project/main.cpp
/project/folder/bar.h
/project/folder/bar.cpp
/project/folder/foo.h
/project/folder/foo.cpp
```

What I want to for SCons to just compile all source files in all subdirectories without having to add a SConscript file in every subdirectory. Basically I want to pass a `Glob('*.cpp')` for /project and all subdirectoires in /project.

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

Answer (score 2):

A recursive globber that worked for me

```
def GlobRecursive(pattern, node='.'):
    results = []
    for f in Glob(str(node) + '/*', source=True):
        if type(f) is SCons.Node.FS.Dir:
            results += GlobRecursive(pattern, f)
    results += Glob(str(node) + '/' + pattern, source=True)
    return results
```

Robᵩ's answer didn't work for me because a) isdir() always returned False (scons 2.5.1) and b) list comprehensions are hard for me to comprehend :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this from the root SConstruct, as follows:

```
env = Environment()
env.Program(source=[Glob('*.cpp'), Glob('folder/*.cpp')], target='yourBinaryName')
```

You will probably also need to configure the include directory as follows:

```
env.Append(CPPPATH='folder')
```

Remeber that Glob() is not recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't want to manually have to enter the names of all the folders. All I want is for all *.cpp files in /project and subdirectories in /project to be compiled.

Comment: @benbalach What you're asking for is called Recursive Glob, and that's not supported in SCons, that's why I mentioned it at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Brady points out, "Glob() is not recursive", but perhaps we could create a recursive globber:

```
def AllSources(node='.', pattern='*'):
    result = [AllSources(dir, pattern)
              for dir in Glob(str(node)+'/*')
              if dir.isdir()]
    result += [source
               for source in Glob(str(node)+'/'+pattern)
               if source.isfile()]
    return result

env = Environment()
env.Program('program', source=AllSources('.', '*.c*'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! I did a bit of searching and this is what I came across:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top

Is your's better or are they basically the same?

Comment: I don't know that either is better. They are different, and will produce different answers under some circumstances. The key difference is that the accepted answer there doesn't use `Glob()`, which considers the SCons state in addition to the filesystem.

Comment: isdir() is always returning False for me (scons 2.5.1)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of globbing by `Glob('*.cpp')` you should also look in the subdirectories using `Glob('**/*.cpp)` and iterate over the received files.