# Iterate over files in multiple directories or an entire hard drive in python

Tags: python, operating-system, glob

I have script.py file which iterates over specific files in the directory where the script.py file is located.

Script looks something like this:

```
def my_funct(l):
     Does stuff:
          iterates over list of files
     Does stuff:
globlist = glob.glob('./*.ext')
my_funct(glob list)
```

I would like to be able to not only iterate over the *.ext files in this directory, but iterate over all the .ext file in all the directories in this directory.

I information I'm reading about os.walk is not making sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code including your attempt at adding 'os.walk' and we can provide feedback

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example for os.walk. It searches for py files in the folder (and all subfolders) and counts the lines:

```
# abspath to a folder as a string
folder = '/home/myname/a_folder/'
# in windows:
# folder = r'C:\a_folder\'
# or folder = 'C:/a_folder/'

count = 0
lines = 0
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for filename in files:
        filename_without_extension, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if extension == '.py':
            count +=1
            with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), 'r') as f:
                for l in f:
                    lines += 1
print count, lines
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm unsure what item should be put in the parenthesis next to os.walk.  Here you have 'folder'.  The documentation is a little weird and other things I've seen are inconsistent with the each other.

Comment: Thanks! That was really slowing me down.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `scandir.walk(path)` insted of `os.walk(path)`. it can give faster result compair to os.walk(). this module is included in python35 but you can use python27,python34 using `pip install scandir`.

my code is here:

```
import os
import scandir

folder = ' ' #here your dir path
print "All files ending with .py in folder %s:" % folder
file_list = []

for paths, dirs, files in scandir.walk(folder):
#for (paths, dirs, files) in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            file_list.append(os.path.join(paths, file))

print len(file_list),file_list
```

scandir.walk() can do exactly what you want in os.walk().

i hope this answer match with your question and here docs for [scandir](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.scandir)

Answer (score 3):

In Python standard library 3.4 and above you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

```
from pathlib import Path

files = Path().cwd().glob("**/*.ext")
```

It will return you generator with all files that have extension ".ext" in current and child directories. You can iterate then over those files

```
for f in files:
    print(f)
    # do other stuff
```

or you can do in one line:

```
for f in Path().cwd().glob("../*.ext"):
    print(f)
    # do other stuff
```