# Remove a set string from many directories in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder `/users/my/folder` which contains many folders which all have names that end with `_STAGE copy`. I would like to remove the end of the folder name `_STAGE copy` and keep everything before it in the folder name.

I have found examples to provide the before/after name, but none that will remove a particular string in bulk from many folders within a directory.

This seems painfully simple but I'm having a hard time figuring it out

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think this should bring you on the right foot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28614999/python-truncate-unknown-file-names

Comment: try using: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename

Comment: Try `man find`, look for `-exec`; you don't need to write your own program for this.

Comment: In the shell, you need something like `mv "$dir" "${dir%_STAGE copy}"` for a single directory. Use `find ... -exec` to apply that to all relevant directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it :

```
import os

path = "dir/"
folders = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
for folder in d:
    folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))

for f in folders:
    if f[-11:] == "_STAGE copy":
        os.rename(f, f[:-11])
```

Comment: thanks I'm getting close with this - this seems to work for files that end in `_STAGE COPY` but not folder names themselves

Comment: you wanna change directory names which end in `_STAGE COPY` too ?

Comment: Only folder names, no files. Within a folder I have many folders that all end in `_STAGE copy`, which I would like to remove from the folder names. I don't want to edit any of the actual files within those folders.

Comment: changed my answer, check it again @phenderbender

Comment: still doesn't seem to want to work. I'm trying to print 'folders' to see what the issue may be and it doesn't look like anything is being appended to the list

Comment: edited your response which was able to get me close to the solution, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Still getting the hang of stack overflow, sorry for editing the previous response. Based on some of the replies and further reading I was able to resolve using this:

```
import os

path = '/directory/path/'
folders = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for folder in d:
        folders.append(os.path.join(r, folder))
for f in folders:
    print(f)     

for f in folders:
    if f[-11:] == "_STAGE copy" :
        os.rename(f, f[:-11])
```