# How do I recursively find a specific subfolder name in a directory using Python / Regular expressions?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, recursion

New to Python and programming. I'm using a Mac Air w/ OS X Yosemite version 10.10.2.

I'm looking for a way to recursively find multiple subfolders, with the same name(e.g."Table"), without using a direct path(assuming I don't know what folders they might be in) and read the files within them using regular expressions or Python. Thank you in advance!

```html
import sys
import os, re, sys
import codecs
import glob



files = glob.glob( '*/Table/.*Records.sql' )

with open( 'AllTables1.2.sql', 'w' ) as result:
    for file_ in files:
        print file_
        if len(file_) == 0: continue
        for line in open( file_, 'r' ):
            
            line = re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '', line)
            line = re.sub(r'--.*', '', line)
            line = re.sub('NVARCHAR', 'VARCHAR', line)
            line = re.sub(r'IDENTITY', 'AUTO_INCREMENT', line)
            line = re.sub(r'DEFAULT\D* +','', line)
            line = re.sub(r'\W(1, 1\W)', ' ', line)
        
        
            result.write( line.decode("utf-8-sig"))                 
            

result.close()
```

Comment: And what happens when you run the code above?

Comment: I just get a blank document back.  Thank you for the reply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Comment: Well, start debugging...are you getting the right files from your `glob` call?

Comment: Thank you Darrick and Jack.  I'll debug again and I already tried the suggested post. At best I end up finding all .sql documents in directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.walk`, which comes shippes with python for this purpose. As, the name suggest, `os.walk` will 'walk' thru your directory recursively and return the root, the dir and a list of file found in the dir.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

You will find an example in the link that I gave above.

Hence for your example, you can achieve your goal you consider doing an os.walk, set up a regex to match folders with a given pattern and get the file with the matching name in your list of file.

For instanxe :

```
import os

for root, dir, filelist in os.walk('./'):
    if dir == 'results': # insert logic to find the folder you want 
        for file in filelist:
            if file  == 'xx': # logic to match file name 
                fullpath = os.path.join(root, file) # Get the full path to the file
```

the above example will find your wanted  file names in a particular folder.

Comment: Note that `os.walk` returns a *list* of directories rather than a single directory, so you'd generally want to do something like `for root, dirs, filelist...: for dir in dirs: ...`