# Getting path in python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to use a subprocess in python to run some scripts on linux,
but my path does not work on what I am trying to do..

I am using:

```
subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", DIR4, DIR2 + dirname + /*  + '/*.json'])
```

`DIR4 = path of python, DIR2+dirname` is the directory I want to go into.
From here I want to use all sub directories in `DIR2+dirname` and all json files in all the subdirectories.

so for example:

```
 DIR2+dirname = /tmp/test/
```

in the `/tmp/test/` directory, there are `/tt1, /tt2, /tt3` 
each `/tt` directories contains `1.json, 2.json, 3.json`
How can I call this all using my command all the way on top?

Comment: Do you want to find the json files in all subdirectories recursively, or just in the directory plus one level of subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module:

```
import os.path
import glob
jsons = glob.glob(os.path.join(DIR2, dirname, '*', '*.json'))
subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", DIR4] + jsons)
```

Comment: I am getting `Usage: python LIMSQCstats.py inputFile.json` and not doing what it should do @tzaman

Answer (score 0):

Use the accepted answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python), starting with `DIR2+dirname` as the path to find all your JSON files.

This snippet was copied from there and slightly adapted:

```
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(DIR2 + dirname):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.json'):
      matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

subprocess.Popen(["nohup", "python", DIR4] + matches)
```

If you have many files, keep in mind that there is an OS-specific limit on command line length, see this [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/163371/linux-command-line-character-limit).