# Get path of all .txt files in a folder and subfolders

Tags: python

I have to get path of all files from a folder, with a specific extension, let's say .txt ( I thing it's the same for another extension) and put them in a .txt file. The problem is that in the folder, are others folders with other .txt files, and I need the path from them too. 
I wrote a code, but it's not working for subfolders. Can anybody help?

```
list1=[]; 

outputFilePath = 'C:\...\playlist.txt'

with open("C:\\...\\folderPath2.txt","r") as f:
    output = f.readline()


for dir_, _, files in os.walk(output):
    for fileName in files:
                relDir = os.path.abspath(output)
                relFile = os.path.join(relDir, fileName)
                list1.append(relFile)   


with open(outputFilePath, 'r+') as file1:
         for lines in list1:
            file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(lines)
            if  (file_extension == '.txt'):
                file1.writelines(lines)
                file1.writelines('\n')
```

Comment: Have you considered using `glob`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something along these lines:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import splitext
from os.path import join

foodir = r"C:\path\to\top\dir"
barlist = list()

for root, dirs, files in walk(foodir):
  for f in files:
    if splitext(f)[1].lower() == ".txt":
      barlist.append(join(root, f))
```

Then you can process barlist however you want. There might be a better way of doing it, but that's what I came up with off the top of my head.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fnmatch.filter` and unix style globbing patterns:

```
import fnmatch
import os
barlist = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('src'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
        barlist.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This will write all of the `.txt` files to a `file_list.txt` file with the full path.

```
import fnmatch
import os

output_file_path = 'file_list.txt'
folder_root = r'e:\myfiles' 

with open(output_file_path, 'w') as f_output:
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder_root):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.txt'):
            f_output.write(os.path.join(root, filename)+'\n')
```