# Logical Error in Python script for comparing two lists

Tags: python, string-comparison

I need to compare a configuration list(req_config) with a pre-existing(masterList) list.

I am getting some logical Error, as code is working fine for some configs and giving false output for other configs. Kindly help.

```
import re
masterList = ['MEMSize', 'conservativeRasEn', 'Height', 'multipleBatch', 'Width', 'dumpAllRegsAtFinish', 'ProtectCtl', 'isdumpEnabled','vh0', 'vw0','lEnable', 'WaveSize','maxLevel','pmVer', 'cSwitchEn', 'disablePreempt', 'disablePreemptInPass', 'ctxSwQueryEn', 'forceEnable', 'enableDebug', '5ErrEn', 'ErrorEn']
req_config = ['MEMSize', 'Height', 'Width', 'isdumpEnabled', 'vh0', 'vw0', 'lEnable', 'WaveSize', 'maxLevel', 'Information', 'ConservativeRasEn']

for config in req_config:
    if any(config in s for s in masterList):
        print "Config matching: ", config
    else:
        print "No match for: ", config
```

### Expected Output:

```
Config matching:  MEMSize
Config matching:  Height
Config matching:  Width
Config matching:  isdumpEnabled
Config matching:  vh0
Config matching:  vw0
Config matching:  lEnable
Config matching:  WaveSize
Config matching:  maxLevel
No match for:  Information
Config matching:  ConservativeRasEn
```

### Current output:

```
Config matching:  MEMSize
Config matching:  Height
Config matching:  Width
Config matching:  isdumpEnabled
Config matching:  vh0
Config matching:  vw0
Config matching:  lEnable
Config matching:  WaveSize
Config matching:  maxLevel
No match for:  Information
No match for:  ConservativeRasEn
```

Comment: `conservativeRasEn` != `ConservativeRasEn` (notice letter case)

Comment: Thank you. I could get the error. Can I please ask you, how to make my comparison case-insensitive. That's the actual requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practise is to normalize the inputs in some form, for example in this case, you may use `str.lower()` to convert the mixed case characters to lowercase characters and then perform comparison:

```
masterList = ['MEMSize', 'conservativeRasEn', 'Height', 'multipleBatch', 'Width', 'dumpAllRegsAtFinish', 'ProtectCtl', 'isdumpEnabled','vh0', 'vw0','lEnable', 'WaveSize','maxLevel','pmVer', 'cSwitchEn', 'disablePreempt', 'disablePreemptInPass', 'ctxSwQueryEn', 'forceEnable', 'enableDebug', '5ErrEn', 'ErrorEn']
req_config = ['MEMSize', 'Height', 'Width', 'isdumpEnabled', 'vh0', 'vw0', 'lEnable', 'WaveSize', 'maxLevel', 'Information', 'ConservativeRasEn']

masterList = map(str.lower, masterList)

for config in req_config:
    if config.lower() in masterList:
        print "Config matching: ", config
    else:
        print "No match for: ", config
```