# Find files of the same type in the same directory with Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to find all the files of a particular file type that is specified and recursively call them to be read until you have read all of the files? (This is in Ubuntu)

For example:

In directory `/home` you have files `a.png`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`, `d.txt`, `e.jpeg`
and I would like to read all the file that are `txt`.

How would one do so in Python?

Sub Question: Is it possible to do what was mentioned above with two different file types?

Comment: I really doubt you're going to be using all of those languages for this, so it sounds like this question is a lot too broad.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Nah, since OP said he only wants use Python, so I removed these tags.

Comment: Sounds like `os.walk` would work for you. Write some code and see how it goes.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) to do this:

```
>>> from glob import glob

>>> glob('/home/*.txt')
['/home/c.txt', '/home/d.txt', '/home/b.txt']

>>> [glob(i) for i in ['/home/*.txt', '/home/*.jpeg']]
[['/home/c.txt', '/home/d.txt', '/home/b.txt'], ['/home/e.jpeg']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the extension of the file to guess the type, you could use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) and filter the files based on the filename:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        # Do what you want to do
```