# How to read all the files of the same type of an arborescence in Python?

Tags: python, file

I am using the [TUH EEG Seizure corpus](https://www.isip.piconepress.com/projects/tuh_eeg/html/downloads.shtml) and I would like to get easily with Python all the files with the same extension. I saw [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34377342/find-files-of-the-same-type-in-the-same-directory-with-python) but I don't know if it can be applied to an overall hierarchy.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`glob` allow to automatically select a pattern in a single directory. `os.walk` is the tool to use for browsing a full hierarchy, but it has no provision for filtering file names on a specific pattern, so you have to apply the filtering *by hand*. You could do:

```
import os.path

# enter your real data here
top_folder = ...
extension = ...

# and let's browse:
for folder, sub_folders, files in os.walk(top_folder)
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(extension):
            full_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
            # apply your processing to full_path
```