# Renaming files recursively to make the filename a concatenation of their path

Tags: python, node.js, bash

Sorry if the title is unclear. An example folder structure to help understand:

```
/images/icons/654/323/64/64/icon.png
/images/icons/837/283/64/64/icon.png
```

to be renamed to

```
/images-icons-654-323-64-64-icon.png
/images-icons-837-283-64-64-icon.png
```

I'm not great at bash so all I have to start with is:

```
find . -name "*.png"
```

which will find all of the files, which I then am hoping to using `-exec rename` with, or whatever works. also open to using any language to get the job done!

Comment: You have the python tag, but you haven't shown any python code.  Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you could do it like so:

```
import fnmatch
import os

def find(base_dir, some_string):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(base_dir):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, some_string):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

    return matches

files = find('.', '*.png')
new_files = ['-'.join(ele.split('/')[1:]) for ele in files]

for idx, ele in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(ele, new_files[idx])
```

And to give proper credit, the `find` function I took from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186565/2323484) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution in bash:

```
for f in $(find images_dir -type f); do 
    mv -v "$f" ${f//\//-}
done
```

This finds all files in the `images_dir` directory, replaces any `/` in their path with `-` thanks to the [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace), and moves the file to the new path.

For example, file `images_dir/icons/654/321/b.png` will be moved to `images_dir-icons-654-321-a.png`.

Note that if you execute `find .`, you will encounter an issue as `find` outputs filenames starting with `./`, which means your files will be renamed to something like `.-<filename>`.

As @gniourf_gniourf notices in the comments, this will fail if your file names include spaces or newlines. 
Whitespace-proof:

```
find images_dir -type f -exec bash -c 'for i; do mv -v "$i" "${i//\//-}; done' _ {} +
```

Comment: This describes exactly what I want, however it did not work for me. I'm getting `sed: -: No such file or directory` (multiple times)

Comment: Which command are you running exactly? I had a similar error when i tried to use sed in the wrong way (giving as argument a string instead of a filename). Here, `-` refers to the piped input, so I'm not sure where this error could come from.

Comment: Running exactly what you posted in a `script.sh` file. It worked when I removed `-` after the `sed` regex before the `)`. however I changed `images_dir` to `./` and that made things real ugly haha, fortunately had a backup

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this hyphen could cause issues! I'll know for later :)

Comment: And I hadn't thought about `./` indeed :D to fix it you could have simply done `for f in $(find ./ -type f); do mv -v $f $(echo $f |  sed 's/.-//' ); done`, which moves all `.-<filename>` files to `<filename>`.

Comment: That's a horrible answer: you're parsing the output of `find`, you lack lots of quotes, you're using an external `sed` while parameter expansions would do the job much better. I'm not going to thank you for spreading bad shell coding over SO.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm curious, why is parsing the output of find bad? I've fixed the quotes and learnt about parameter expansion, thanks for that!

Comment: Bad in case filename contains spaces or glob characters.

Comment: One possibility: use a `while` loop with `read` and process substitution: `while IFS= read -r f; do ...; done < <(find ...)`. This will still break if filenames contain newlines; to be more robust, you need a version of `find` that handles `-print0` (GNU `find` does) and use: `while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do ...; done < <(find ... -print0)`. (cont'd)…

Comment: But the best way to use `find` is to not parse its output at all. E.g., `find images_dir -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -v "$1" "${1//\//-}"' _ {} \;`, or, even better `find images_dir -type f -exec bash -c 'for i; do mv -v "$i" "${i//\//-}; done' _ {} +`. Note that this doesn't fix the slash of `./` being replaced by `-`.

Comment: thanks @gniourf_gniourf, I've updated my answer again!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
for file in `find image -iname "*.png"`
do
  newfile=`echo "$file" | sed 's=/=-=g'`
  mv -v $file $newfile
done
```

The backtick `find` command will expand to a list of files ending with ".png", the `-iname` performs the search in a case independent manner.

The `sed` command will replace all slashes with dashes, resulting in the new target name.

The `mv` does the heavy lifting.  The `-v` is optional and will cause a verbose move.

To debug, you can put an `echo` statement in front of the `mv`.

Comment: Getting this error: ./script.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./script.sh: line 6: `  newfile=`echo "$file" | sed 's=/=-/'`'

Comment: The backticks make the error unclear due to formatting issues, I've posted it here: https://gist.github.com/elzii/56f3ca4d4f94dc29e955

Comment: That's a horrible answer: you're parsing the output of `find`, you lack lots of quotes, you're using an external sed while parameter expansions would do the job much better. I'm not going to thank you for spreading bad shell coding over SO.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I make no apologies.  This is code that should run portably in both bash and sh and uses a few straightforward shell concepts.

Comment: @elzi: I do apologize to you; I fat-fingered a couple of things besides the quotes, in the original answer, but the code is fixed now and should work.

Comment: You mean _broken_ shell _misconceptions,_ don't you? your command is broken with filenames containing spaces or glob characters. Please be aware that parsing `find` has been recognized for a rather long while as being broken and very bad practice. See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and all the links it contains.