# using glob.glob recursively while also utilizing .format syntax

Tags: python, recursion, glob

This is my first question, and I'm a Python newbie.
Using Python 3.5.

I want to use glob recursively, and found this answer regarding using glob recursively very helpful: [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

However, I also want to utilize a looped variable, and can't seem to figure out the correct syntax. 
This returns a list just fine:

```
x = glob.glob(('{0}*.txt').format(some_variable))
```

This is the "recursive" syntax supplied by the answer to the glob.glob question I linked to, above, which works great and returns a list:

```
x = glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive = True)
```

So far, so good. But when I try this, I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'format'":

```
x = glob.glob('**/{0}*.txt', recursive = True).format(some_variable)
```

I also tried this, which gives and "invalid syntax" error:

```
x = glob.glob(('**/{0}*.txt').format(some_variable)), recursive = True)
```

I bet I'm getting something wrong in a very basic sense, or perhaps I just can't use .format syntax with the recursive version of glob that I'm trying here? I think there are other ways of doing this recursively, but I still am confused as to why the first syntax I'm trying doesn't work.

Any input is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = glob.glob('**/{0}*.txt'.format(some_variable), recursive = True)
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much. I could have sworn I tried that. Sigh. I appreciate your quick response!