# Python script not combining csv files

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to combine over 100,000 CSV files (all same formats) in a folder using below script.  Each CSV file is on average 3-6KB of size.  When I run this script, it only opens exact 47 .csv files and combines.  When I re-run it only combines same .csv files, not all of them.   I don't understand why it is doing that?

```
import os
import glob

os.chdir("D:\Users\Bop\csv")    

want_header = True
out_filename = "combined.files.csv"          

if os.path.exists(out_filename):
    os.remove(out_filename)

read_files = glob.glob("*.csv")

with open(out_filename, "w") as outfile:
    for filename in read_files:
        with open(filename) as infile:
            if want_header:
                outfile.write('{},Filename\n'.format(next(infile).strip()))
                want_header = False
            else:
                next(infile)
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write('{},{}\n'.format(line.strip(), filename))
```

Comment: Does `read_files` actually contain all 100000 files? (which is an awful lot of files in the same directory.)

Comment: You don't need to check for and remove the output file first, if you open it with [mode `"w"`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: do some filenames start with a dot '.'? Is there some where the 'csv' extension is in a different case? I would just check (even running in the python CLI) what the result of the glob.glob() function is and go from there..

Comment: How can I check read_files actually contains all the files?   Files are named like this:  "file0000001, file000002, etc..."

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check the length of read_files:

```
read_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
print(len(read_files))
```

Note that glob isn't necessarily recursive [as described in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python).

Otherwise your code looks fine. You may want to consider using the CSV library but note that you need to adjust the field size limit with [really large files](http://lethain.com/handling-very-large-csv-and-xml-files-in-python/).

Comment: As the "combined file" gets larger combining all those 100,000 csv files, it will get hundreds of megabite in size.  Will that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Are you shure your all filenames ends with `.csv`? If all files in this directory contains what you need, then open all of them without filtering.

```
glob.glob('*')
```