# How to loop, print and save outputs in an array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, glob

I am a new user to Python and am trying to loop the following:

```
text = open('filename.txt', 'rU').read()  
splitter = Splitter()
postagger = POSTagger()
splitted_sentences = splitter.split(text)
pos_tagged_sentences = postagger.pos_tag(splitted_sentences)
dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([ 'dicts/positive.yml', 'dicts/negative.yml'])
dict_tagged_sentences = dicttagger.tag(pos_tagged_sentences)
scoreposneg = sentiment_score(dict_tagged_sentences)
dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([ 'dicts/positive.yml', 'dicts/negative.yml', 'dicts/inc.yml', 'dicts/dec.yml', 'dicts/inv.yml'])
dict_tagged_sentences = dicttagger.tag(pos_tagged_sentences)
scoretotal = sentiment_total(dict_tagged_sentences)
print scoretotal
```

Prior to this, I have set up class for Splitter, POSTagger, DictionaryTagger, sentiment_total and also created 5 different dictionaries. This works when I run it on Python for 1 filen(I got a number from print scoretotal). However, when I tried to create a loop and print all the outputs (I have 650 files in my directory), it didn't work (nothing was printed) and the scoretext.txt file had 0.0 in them.

```
path = '/mydirectory'
files = glob.glob(path)
for file in files:
    text = open(file, 'rU').read()
    splitter = Splitter()
    postagger = POSTagger()
    splitted_sentences = splitter.split(text)
    pos_tagged_sentences = postagger.pos_tag(splitted_sentences)
    dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([ 'dicts/positive.yml', 'dicts/negative.yml'])
    dict_tagged_sentences = dicttagger.tag(pos_tagged_sentences)
    scoreposneg = sentiment_score(dict_tagged_sentences)
    dicttagger = DictionaryTagger([ 'dicts/positive.yml', 'dicts/negative.yml', 'dicts/inc.yml', 'dicts/dec.yml', 'dicts/inv.yml'])
    dict_tagged_sentences = dicttagger.tag(pos_tagged_sentences)
    scoretotal = sentiment_total(dict_tagged_sentences)
    print scoretotal

scoretotal = np.zeros((1,650))
scoretotal_no = 0
scoretotal_no = scoretotal_no + 1

np.savetxt("scoretext.txt", scoretotal, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
```

Would really appreciate if someone can provide some insights on this. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this is supposed to do (`scoretotal` is reset outside the loop?) but what do you get from `print(files)` before `for file in files:`? Also, `file` is a builtin in Python 2.x so I would choose another name.

Comment: Hi Roganjosh, what i got was [] . I've changed file to filename. I thought I'm saving the 650 scores into an array so it has to be out of the loop

Comment: Ok, so firstly the loop itself doesn't work because `path = '/mydirectory'` is giving you an empty list in `files = glob.glob(path)` (there is nothing to iterate through). That isolates one issue. But `scoretotal = np.zeros((1,650))` completely destroys any data you might have accumulated during the loops for `scoretotal`. In fact, each loop will just destroy data from the previous iteration (I assume, but I don't know what `sentiment_total()` does).

Comment: I've def the sentiment_total (def sentiment_total(review):
    return sum([sentence_score(sentence, None, 0.0) for sentence in review])) to return a score of the text. Would you recommend to loop using i and range instead?

Comment: It's not really possible to know what you should be doing, but your loop cannot work because `files = glob.glob(path)` is returning an empty list. You first problem is _before_ your `for` loop anyway, so that needs fixing before you get to the loop.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, I understand better now

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be how you access the files in the directory.  See this:
[Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Comment: Hi Nick, I've also tried (but it also didn't work): 
    directory = os.path.join("/textanalysisfiles","path")
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:

Comment: Agree with @roganjosh ,file is a reserved name in python, so use something else, even: for files in file_list