# open file with specific types in python

Tags: python, glob, file-type

I want to open the files in a directory with the following specific file types entered by users:

```
if type is not None:
    for file in glob.glob(dir + "/" + type):
        if os.path.isfile(file):
            open_file(file)
        if os.path.isdir(file):
            open_folder(file)
```

Type is "t" as an argument parser variable standing for file types, D is dir:

```
$ python scan.py -D /home/ -t .php
```

But it just gives an empty output rather than an expected result with .php files.

---

Comment: So, your glob statement is `glob.glob('/home//php')` What do you expect this to find?

Comment: Try adding a wildcard before the file extension on your glob pattern `glob.glob(dir + '/*.' + type)`

Comment: still empty, I have played around this section , no positive responds given. @HuyLe

Comment: I suspect you want recursive glob `glob.glob(base_dir + "/**/*." + my_type, recursive=True)`

Comment: @HuyLe it works like a charm. Thanks so much, but it will be my day if you can give a bit explanation about this recursive why I need to you "/**/*." instead

Comment: You should use `os.path.join` rather than manually concatenating strings. It'll buy you cleaner code and cross platform code, if done correctly. Also using the variable name [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#type), Its a built in name.

Comment: `**` is the globstar pattern, `**/` will match the current directory and all sub-directories under current path, the rest `*.<extension>` is as you expected. `recursive=True` argument is required by python to enable the use of globstar as it implies performance impacts

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
import glob
path = "/home/yourdir/*.php"
for filename in glob.glob(path, recursive=True):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print line,
```

For more [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python).

Comment: it's similar scenario but different purposes. The path and type are given by users. My code got stuck when the directory contains so many sub-folders in it, it won't give the file types @Shailesh

Answer (score 0):

[path.py](https://github.com/jaraco/path.py) could be what you want.

Install path.py

```
pip install path.py
```

And use walkfiles with a pattern.

```
import path
D = "/home/yourdir"
T = ".php"

for filename in path.Path(D).walkfiles(pattern= "*"+T):
    print(filename)
```