# Copy all .csv files in a directory of folders to one folder in python

Tags: python, csv, shutil

I am trying to copy all .csv files within a parent folder and all sub-folders within, to a new destination ("C:/Projects/CSVFiles").

I have used the following code(from elsewhere on the forum) but this only copies the .csv files in the parent directory (DataFiles) and not from the sub-folders within /datafiles/.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks

```
import glob
import shutil
import os

src_dir = "C:/Projects/DataFiles"
dst_dir = "C:/Projects/CSVFiles"
for CSVfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "*.csv")):
shutil.copy(Excelfile, dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `os.walk` to traverse the directory tree.

```
import os
import shutil
src_dir = "C:/Projects/DataFiles"
dst_dir = "C:/Projects/CSVFiles"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,f), dst_dir)
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting from python 3.5, `glob` supports [the `recursive` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
glob.iglob(os.path.join(src_dir, "**", "*.csv"), recursive=True)
```

---

In older python versions you can use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) instead:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith('.csv'):
            continue

        filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.2 to 3.4

```
import fnmatch
import os

src_dir = "C:/Projects/DataFiles"
dst_dir = "C:/Projects/CSVFiles"

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src_dir):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.csv'):
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, filename),dst_dir)
```

Ref: [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)