# How to batch convert RAW images in several subfolders to DNG

Tags: macos, image, dng

So I have 20 subfolders full of files in my main folder and have around 200 files in every subfolder. I've been trying to write a script to convert **every picture** in **every subfolder** to DNG.
I have done some research and was able to batch convert images from the current folder.
I've tried developping the idea to get it to work for subfolders but to no success.
Here is the code I've written:

```
for D in 'find . -type d'; do for i in *.RW2; do sips -s format jpeg $i --out "${i%.*}.jpg"; cd ..; done; done;
```

Comment: If your current problem is that you can't recursively glob for a certain extension, then it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python

Comment: That line of code does not look like Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *easiest* and *fastest* way to do this is with **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
find . -iname \*rw2 -print0 | parallel -0 sips -s format jpeg --out {.}.jpg {}
```

because that will use all your CPU cores in parallel. But before you launch any commands you haven't tested, it is best to use the `--dry-run` option like this so that it shows you what it is going to do, but without actually doing anything:

```
find . -iname \*rw2 -print0 | parallel --dry-run -0 sips -s format jpeg --out {.}.jpg {}
```

**Sample Output**

```
sips -s format jpeg --out ./sub1/b.jpg ./sub1/b.rw2
sips -s format jpeg --out ./sub1/a.jpg ./sub1/a.RW2
sips -s format jpeg --out ./sub2/b.jpg ./sub2/b.rw2
```

If you like the way it looks, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again. Note that the `-iname` parameter means it is **insensitive** to upper/lower case, so it will work for "*.RW2" and "*.rw2".

---

**GNU Parallel** is easily installed on macOS via **homebrew** with:

```
brew install parallel
```

It can also be installed without a package manager (like **homebrew**) because it is actually a Perl script and Macs come with Perl. So you can install by doing this in Terminal:

```
(wget pi.dk/3 -qO - ||  curl pi.dk/3/) | bash
```

---

Your question seems confused as to whether you want `DNG` files like your title suggests, or `JPEG` files like your code suggests. My code generates JPEGs as it stands. If you want `DNG` output, you will need to install **Adobe DNG Converter**, and then run:

```
find . -iname \*rw2 -print0 | parallel --dry-run -0 \"/Applications/Adobe DNG Converter.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe DNG Converter\"
```

There are some other options you can append to the end of the above command:

- `-e` will *embed* the original `RW2` file in the `DNG`
- `-u` will create the `DNG` file uncompressed
- `-fl` will add *fast load* information to the `DNG`

**DNG Converter** seems happy enough to run multiple instances in parallel, but I did not test with thousands of files. If you run into issues, just run one job at a time by changing to `parallel -j 1 ...`

---

**Adobe DNG Converter** is easily installed under macOS using **homebrew** as follows:

```
brew install caskroom/cask/adobe-dng-converter
```