# Python Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 19 to the 15 allowed

Tags: python, python-2.7, sonarlint

I see this message from sonarlint and trying to figure out how to reduce the Cognitive Complexity of this function. Any assistance is appreciated in advance.

```
import os
import json
import click
import hcl

cfn = [".json", ".template", ".yaml", ".yml"]
tf  = ["tf"]

def file_handler(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(tuple(cfn)):
                with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fin:
                    try:
                        file = fin.read()
                        if "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" in file:
                            data = json.dumps(file)
                            print(data)

                    except ValueError as e:
                        raise SystemExit(e)

            elif file.endswith(tuple(tf)):
                with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as file:
                    try:
                        obj  = hcl.load(file)
                        data = json.dumps(obj)
                        print(data)
                    except ValueError as e:
                        raise SystemExit(e)
    return data
```

Comment: What metrix tool are you using to get the resulting numbers?

Comment: Extract functions, create handler lookups for file types, unify error handling, remove duplication, etc, etc.

Comment: You're probably better posting on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Extract function to yield file paths:

```
def _file_paths(directory):
    for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in filenames:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                yield file_path
```

Unify exception handling:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def _translate_error(from_error, to_error):
    try:
        yield
    except from_error as error:
        raise to_error(error)
```

Extract functions to handle file types:

```
def _handle_cfn(file_object):
    file_contents = file_object.read()
    if "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" in file_contents:
        data = json.dumps(file_contents)
        print(data)


def _handle_tf(file_object):
    obj  = hcl.load(file_oject)
    data = json.dumps(obj)
    print(data)
```

Create a null handler for when the file extension doesn't match:

```
def _null_handler(file_object):
    pass
```

Map file extensions to handlers:

```
_extension_handlers = {'.json': _handle_cfn,
            '.template': _handle_cfn,
            '.yaml': _handle_cfn,
            '.yml': _handle_cfn,
            '.tf': _handle_tf}
```

Putting it together:

```
import os
import json
import click
import hcl

def file_handler(dir):
    for file_path in _file_paths(dir):
        base, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
        handler = _extension_handlers.get(extension, _null_handler)
        with open(file_path) as file_object:
            with _translate_error(ValueError, SystemExit):
                handler(file_object)
```

You can go further by extracting out a function for handling each file:

```
def _handle_file(file_path):
    base, extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)
    handler = _extension_handlers.get(extension, _null_handler)
    with open(file_path) as file_object:
        with _translate_error(ValueError, SystemExit):
            handler(file_object)
```

Then your main function is:

```
def file_handler(dir):
    for file_path in _file_paths(dir):
        _handle_file(file_path)
```

Comment: I'd recommend the second-to-last `file_handler` (non-`map` based); `map` is for functional programming, and shouldn't be used for side-effects (needlessly creating useless temporary `list`s on Python 2, and not working at all on Python 3 without additional changes).

Comment: @ShadowRanger agreed, will remove without explanation, as it's more than needed.

Comment: This worked.

    def _file_paths(directory):
        for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                path = os.path.join(root, filename)
                if os.path.isfile(path):
                    yield path

Comment: @kilomo edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You can remove one level of indentation by using two generator expressions for filtering the files by extension:

```
def file_handler(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        cfn_files = (file for file in files if file.endswith(tuple(cfn)))
        tf_files = (file for file in files if file.endswith(tuple(tf)))
        for file in cfn_files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as fin:
                try:
                    file = fin.read()
                    if "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" in file:
                        data = json.dumps(file)
                        print(data)
                except ValueError as e:
                    raise SystemExit(e)
        for file in tf_files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') as file:
                try:
                    obj  = hcl.load(file)
                    data = json.dumps(obj)
                    print(data)
                except ValueError as e:
                    raise SystemExit(e)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `glob` for recursive file finding especially when you know what file extensions you're looking for:

```
import glob
import json
import os

import click
import hcl

def file_handler(dir):
    for extension in cfn:
        # eg: /path/to/dir/**/*.json
        glob_search = os.path.join(dir, "**/*{}".format(extension))  
        filenames = glob.glob(glob_search, recursive=True)

        for filename in filenames:
            with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
                try:
                    file = fin.read()
                    if "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" in file:
                        data = json.dumps(file)
                        print(data)

                except ValueError as e:
                    raise SystemExit(e)

    for extension in tf:
        # eg: /path/to/dir/**/*tf
        glob_search = os.path.join(dir, "**/*{}".format(extension))
        filenames = glob.glob(glob_search, recursive=True)

        for filename in filenames:
            with open(filename, 'r') as file:
                try:
                    obj = hcl.load(file)
                    data = json.dumps(obj)
                    print(data)
                except ValueError as e:
                    raise SystemExit(e)
```

FYI: A question about using glob ([Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python))