# Python glob: how input directories and single files

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, hierarchy, glob

This is an easy question.

I'm using glob to print the full hierarchy of a folder using this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import argparse
import sys
import glob

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                              
parser.add_argument('-input', dest='input',help="input one or more files",metavar=None)                     
args = parser.parse_args()

def dirlist(path):

    for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*")):
        if os.path.isfile(i):
            print (i)

        elif os.path.isdir(i):
            dirname = os.path.basename(i)               
            dirlist(i)

path = os.path.normpath(args.input)
dirlist(path)
```

It works pretty well, you just need to run `python3 Test.py -input .`.

As you can see by the `argparse` help description I would like to input directories but also single files.

I don't think this can be done using `glob`, is that right?

Can you suggest me a library that could help me **print the full hierarchy of both directories and files**?

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python) a long list of `globe` examples but they all seems to work for directories, not when you input a single file

Comment: I think you need to look at `os.walk()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is nearly midnight but at least I found the solution after 2 days:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import argparse
import sys
import glob

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                              
parser.add_argument('-input', dest='input',help="input one or more files",metavar=None)                     
args = parser.parse_args()

def dirlist(path):

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        print (path)
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
        for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*")):
            if os.path.isfile(i):
                print (i)

            elif os.path.isdir(i):
                dirname = os.path.basename(i)               
                dirlist(i)


path = os.path.normpath(args.input)
dirlist(path)
```