# Getting a list of all files (with absolute path) recursively and their uid with Python

Tags: python, list, file, absolute-path, uid

I am trying to write a python script to list all files with absolute path in a given directory recursively and list their UID and file owners in front of them. (something like: ls -lR )
I wrote this one but it gives me an error at the end of execution:

```
import os
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.abspath(file)
        print(filePath, os.stat(file).st_uid)
```

Comment: And the error is....what?

Comment: We can't help you without all the relevant info, like the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import os
import glob

for filename in glob.iglob('./**/*', recursive=True):
    print(os.path.abspath(filename), os.stat(filename).st_uid)
```

Needs Python 3.5 or higher
[Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python)

Comment: Thank you so much #humodz ! That's exactly what I am looking for. Is there any way to store the out put in to the database (mysql or sqligh) ?

Answer (score 3):

`files` are just the filenames themselves, **not** the path to the files from your current location.

Try

```
import os
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
    for file in files:
        filePath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, file))
        print(filePath, os.stat(file).st_uid)
```

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.abspath()` doesn't do what you think it does. It more or less just prepends the result of `getcwd()` to the string you pass, it doesn't know anything about where that file actually is. So when your loop gets to a name in a subdirectory, the `abspath()` is wrong, since the current directory is still the level above.

You can get the correct directory name from the output of `os.walk`, see the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk).