# os.path.join but extract item of a list

Tags: python, loops

I want to do an os.path.join that contains a list in `filenames` because there are 3 files in that final folder. I want to only use the PST.shp

```
import os
fo = []
f = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\folder1'
for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(f):      
        print(filenames)
        #fo.append(os.path.join(dirpath,filenames))
```

gives:

```
[]
[]
['PST.dbf', 'PST.shp', 'PST.shx']
[]
['PST.dbf', 'PST.shp', 'PST.shx']
[]
['PST.dbf', 'PST.shp', 'PST.shx']
[]
['PST.dbf', 'PST.shp', 'PST.shx']
[]
```

How to filter so I use only the `PST.shp` full path in the list `fo`?

something like:

```
 fo = []
    f = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\folder\folder1'
    for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(f):  
         if filenames not empty:    
            print(filenames)
            fo.append(os.path.join(dirpath,filenames[0][1]))
```

Comment: Check if `PST.shp` is in `filenames`. If yes `append` the path. ie, `fo.append(os.path.join(dirpath, 'PST.shp'))`

Comment: Since Python 3.5 `glob` is recursive so you could use that. See [Use a Glob() to find files recursively in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python) which also has pre-3.5 solutions.

Comment: See [**`fnmatch`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html).

Comment: ok this worked but is it possible to do it without referring to the name but use index?

Comment: @PeterWood Write an answer if you want with fnmatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that you will only use the script to process a PST shape, just follow @AbdulNiyasPM's advice and check and process the `PST.shp` file:

```
     ...
     if filenames not empty:    
        print(filenames)
        if 'PST.shp' in filenames:
            fo.append(os.path.join(dirpath, 'PST.shp'))
```

If you want to keep any `shp` file, you can simple test that pattern:

```
     ...
     if filenames not empty:    
        print(filenames)
        for name in filenames:
            if name.endswith('.shp'):
                fo.append(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
```

Beware: if you need to be able to support non case sensitive platforms like Windows (ie: if you want to accept file names like `xx.Shp` or `yy.SHP`) a simple `str.endswith` is not enough, and you should use `fnmatch` or at least a non case sensitive regex (thanks to Peter Wood for his remark).

Comment: What if the filename is uppercase, `'PST.SHP'`? It would be safer to use [**`fnmatch`**](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fnmatch.html) as it deals with case based on operating system support.

Answer (score 0):

Use `endswith` function to check for extensiton as follows,

```
for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(f):  
   for f in filenames:
       if f.endswith('.shp'):
          fo.append(os.path.join(dirpath,f))
```