# How to exclude directory in os.walk()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to search my computer drives D to Z for all vhdx files, and calculate the total amount of them. But I want to exclude directories. How to change my code?

```
extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information']
```

```py
import os
i = 0
az = lambda: (chr(i)+":\\" for i in range(ord("D"), ord("Z") + 1))
for drv in az():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drv):
        for filename in files:
            splitname = filename.split('.')
            if splitname[-1] !="vhdx":
                continue
            file_path = (os.path.join(root, filename))
            print file_path
            i += 1
    if i != 0:
        print ("total vhdx files:",i)
```

Comment: You iterate over files only so what directory you talk about?

Comment: If you are using python3.5+, try `pathlib`

Comment: @WaketZheng or [**`glob`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i usually exclude directories when iterating over [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?#os.walk):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(drv):
    dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
```

the point here is to use a [slice-assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) (`dirs[:] = ...`) in order to change `dirs` in-place (reassigning `dirs` to the newly created list).

if you want to have a slight speedup, i suggest to turn `extf` into a `set`:

```
extf = set(('$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information'))
```

Answer (score 0):

An example for you:

```
from pathlib import Path
i = 0
az = lambda: (chr(i)+":\\" for i in range(ord("D"), ord("Z") + 1))

for d in az():
    p = Path(d)
    if not p.exists():
        continue
    i += len(list(p.rglob('*.vhdx')))
print("total vhdx files:", i)
```